# What is the proper declaration of main in C++?

Tags: c++, function, language-lawyer, program-entry-point, c++-faq

### Questions

- What is the proper signature of the `main` function in C++?
- What is the correct return type, and what does it mean to return a value from `main`?
- What are the allowed parameter types, and what are their meanings?
- Is this system-specific?
- Have those rules changed over time?
- What happens if I violate them?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler No kidding... it was added to the list of duplicates in [revision 6](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/204476/6) about 8 months ago.

Comment: This question is not an exact duplicate of the [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c). However, everything that it asks is already answered over there in greater detail and in greater quality, which makes this question a duplicate. This question is also problematic in its current state because it's not very focused, and is asking about system-specifics, historical changes, and all sorts of things just to forcefully distinguish itself. This in itself might warrant a "needs focus" close reason.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

The `main` function must be declared as a non-member function in the global namespace.  This means that it cannot be a static or non-static member function of a class, nor can it be placed in a namespace (even the unnamed namespace).

The name `main` is not reserved in C++ except as a function in the global namespace.  You are free to declare other entities named `main`, including among other things, classes, variables, enumerations, member functions, and non-member functions not in the global namespace.

You can declare a function named `main` as a member function or in a namespace, but such a function would not be the `main` function that designates where the program starts.

The `main` function cannot be declared as `static` or `inline`.  It also cannot be overloaded; there can be only one function named `main` in the global namespace.

The `main` function cannot be used in your program: you are not allowed to call the `main` function from anywhere in your code, nor are you allowed to take its address.

**The return type of `main` must be `int`**.  No other return type is allowed (this rule is in bold because it is very common to see incorrect programs that declare `main` with a return type of `void`; this is probably the most frequently violated rule concerning the `main` function).

There are two declarations of `main` that must be allowed:

```
int main()               // (1)
int main(int, char*[])   // (2)
```

In **(1)**, there are no parameters.

In **(2)**, there are two parameters and they are conventionally named `argc` and `argv`, respectively.  `argv` is a pointer to an array of C strings representing the arguments to the program. `argc` is the number of arguments in the `argv` array.

Usually, `argv[0]` contains the name of the program, but this is not always the case.  `argv[argc]` is guaranteed to be a null pointer.

Note that since an array type argument (like `char*[]`) is really just a pointer type argument in disguise, the following two are both valid ways to write **(2)** and they both mean exactly the same thing:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

Some implementations may allow other types and numbers of parameters; you'd have to check the documentation of your implementation to see what it supports.

`main()` is expected to return zero to indicate success and non-zero to indicate failure.  You are not required to explicitly write a `return` statement in `main()`:  if you let `main()` return without an explicit `return` statement, it's the same as if you had written `return 0;`.  The following two `main()` functions have the same behavior:

```
int main() { }
int main() { return 0; }
```

There are two macros, `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`, defined in `<cstdlib>` that can also be returned from `main()` to indicate success and failure, respectively.

The value returned by `main()` is passed to the `exit()` function, which terminates the program.

Note that all of this applies only when compiling for a hosted environment (informally, an environment where you have a full standard library and there's an OS running your program).  It is also possible to compile a C++ program for a freestanding environment (for example, some types of embedded systems), in which case startup and termination are wholly implementation-defined and a `main()` function may not even be required.  If you're writing C++ for a modern desktop OS, though, you're compiling for a hosted environment.

Comment: IIRC the only guaranteed return values are 0, EXIT_SUCCESS (same effect as 0), and EXIT_FAILURE. EDIT: Ah, OK, other non-zero status values may be returned, but with implementation-defined meaning. Only EXIT_FAILURE is guaranteed to be interpreted in some way as a failure value.

Comment: It would not hurt to specify (just to be sure) that this is in reference to C++. Java/C# users may be confused since those languages actually *require* the entry point to—counterintuitively—be in a class (for some reason). Also, isn't the old `void main` format a holdover from C?

Comment: @Synetech:  The question asks in its first sentence, "What is the proper signature of the main function in C++?" and the question is tagged both [c++] and [c++-faq].  I can't help it if Java or C# users (or anyone else) are still confused.  C# requires `Main` to be a static member function because it doesn't even have nonmember functions.  Even C89 requires `main` to return `int`.  I am not sufficiently familiar with K&R C to know its exact rules, but I would guess it also requires `main` to return `int` since `main` with no return type was somewhat common and no type = implicit `int` in K&R.

Comment: @ James McNellis can you please explain `why the return type of main should be int`?

Comment: @Suhail:  Because the language standard says the return type shall be `int`.

Comment: @ James McNellis Is there any harm if i use `void` ?

Comment: @Suhail:  Yes.  Your code will not be correct C++ and many compilers will reject your code.

Comment: @ James McNellis Oh! thank you! Can you please name some compilers that will reject the `void` return type.I have only used `Visual studio c++` (and also the ancient turbo-c++ ) till now which passes my code.

Comment: @ James McNellis  How come **Microsoft's compiler** pass the code with `void` return type of `main` . **(microsoft visual c++ 2010 express edition)**

Comment: @Suhail:  Visual C++ permits a `void` return type [as a language extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh.aspx).  Compilers that do not permit it include GCC and Comeau.

Comment: Has the int main() {} version *always* been part of the standard or is it something that was added recently?

Comment: It was added to C more than fifty years ago, long before there was C++ standard.

Comment: On less-common platforms (e.g., VAX/VMS), with compilers that followed very old versions of the then-more-ambiguous C standard, `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` were only reliable as arguments to `exit()`.  Returning either of them from `main()` could have unintended effects.  Now that the standard has been clarified, there's no standard, portable way to return a completely arbitrary value to the host environment; you'd have to use a host-specific extension.

Answer (score 15):

From Standard docs., *3.6.1.2 Main Function*,

> **It shall have a return
>   type of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined.** All implementations shall allow both of the following
>   definitions of main:

`int main() { / ... / }` and
`int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { / ... / }`

> In the latter form `argc` shall be the **number of arguments passed to the program** from the environment in which the
>   program is run.If argc is nonzero **these arguments shall be supplied in argv[0] through argv[argc-1] as pointers to
>   the initial characters of null-terminated multibyte strings**.....

Hope that helps..

Comment: is there any specific reason as to why the return type of `main` should be `int` ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta: So that the calling process knows whether _this_ process should be deemed successful or not. Allowing `void` breaks that model. It doesn't even really make sense if you had it mean "always deem success". Because you had no way of saying if the process actually failed, so did you _really_ succeed? No, return `int`.

Answer (score 3):

The two valid mains are `int main()` and `int main(int, char*[])`. Any thing else may or may not compile. If `main` doesn't explicitly return a value, **0** is implicitly returned.

Comment: I have never seen code not getting compiled when i mention the return type of `main` to be void. **Is there any specific reason that return type of main should be int ?**

Comment: The language specification says main must have a return type of int.  Any other return type allowed by your compiler is a compiler specific enhancement. Basically using void means you are programming in a language similar to but not C++.

Comment: The reason the standard requires an `int` as the return type of `main` is that this value is handed to the shell as the program's exit code, and `sh` expects an `int`.

Comment: Maybe the reason is discipline? There can be more than one path out.  If the return type is `void` they are all silent. With `int` we have to define the specific exit-value for each return from `main`.

Answer (score 3):

The exact wording of the latest published standard (C++14) is:

> An implementation  shall allow both
>
> - a function of `()` returning `int` and
> - a function of `(int`, pointer to pointer to `char)` returning `int`
>
> as the type of `main`.

This makes it clear that alternative spellings are permitted so long as the type of `main` is the type `int()` or `int(int, char**)`. So the following are also permitted:

- `int main(void)`
- `auto main() -> int`
- `int   main (    )`
- `signed int main()`
- `typedef char **a; typedef int b, e; e main(b d, a c)`

Comment: NB. I posted this answer as in comments to another thread, someone tried to cite this thread as evidence that `int main(void)` was not correct in C++.

Comment: @Stargateur `auto main() -> int` does not have a deduced return type. Pay attention to the { in "(auto main() {... is not allowed)" and please learn to know when you don't yet know enough to add anything meaningful.

Comment: bullet #5 got a chuckle out of me...reminds me of the DIKUMUD era of my programming.  TypeDef a TypeDef to define a TypeDef ;)

Answer (score 2):

**Details on return values and their meaning**

Per 3.6.1 (`[basic.start.main]`):

> A return statement in `main` has the effect of leaving the `main` function (destroying any objects with automatic storage duration) and calling `std::exit` with the return value as the argument. If control reaches the end of `main` without encountering a `return` statement, the effect is that of executing
>
> ```
> return 0;
> ```

The behavior of `std::exit` is detailed in section 18.5 (`[support.start.term]`), and describes the status code:

> Finally,  control is returned to the host environment.   If  status is zero or `EXIT_SUCCESS`, an implementation-defined form of the status successful termination is returned. If status is `EXIT_FAILURE`, an implementation-defined  form of the status unsuccessful termination is returned.  Otherwise the status returned is implementation-defined.