# C++ while problem

Tags: c++

I have a problem with while loop in c++.
I write this code:

```
#include <iostream.h>
main () {
    int a, av = 0;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> a;

        for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
            while (av == 1) {
                cout << "abc" << a / i;
                if (a % i == 0) {
                    av = 1;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

This program should print "abc", but it doesn't print any thing.
I know the problem is in while section, but how can I fix it?
Thanks ..

Comment: [The return type of `main()` must be `int`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main/4207223#4207223).  The standard library header is named `<iostream>` (no `.h`).  The standard library entities are in the `std` namespace and must be qualified (e.g. `std::cout`, `std::cin`, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `while (av == 0)` to get in the inner loop.

Answer (score 3):

`av` is 0 when you get to the while loop so the condition `av==1` is always false.

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning, `av` is equal to 0.  Its value never gets changed, because the while loop is never entered (since av is NOT equal to 1).

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize `av` to 1. Try changing your first statement to:

```
int a, av = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the while loop will never be entered since av = 0 and the loop predicate is av == 1.

Answer (score 0):

Two cases when abc would not be printed:

1 : The user enters 0 as the input for 'a'  - The for loop is exited in the first loop itself as i would never be 0.

2 : initial value of av is 0 and and **while (av==1)** would never be true irrespective of the number of times the 'for' loop is run

to print abc:

Set av == 1 initially or make sure user enter a number > 0 always

> **OR**
>
> change the code as follows:
>   while (av == 1) {
>                   cout << "abc" << a / i;
>                   }
>                   if (a % i == 0) 
>                       av = 1;