# C++ Validations doubts

Tags: c++, validation

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{

    char fname[11]; 
    int x = 0; 

    cout << "Please enter the name: "; 
    cin >> fname;

    while (fname[x] != '\0') 
    { 
        int i=int(fname[x]);
        if (i>=97)
            cout << fname[x]; 
        x++; 
    } 

    else    
        cout << "Invalid characters";

    system("pause");
}
```

I tried to validate char input by using above codes.
But couldn't do it.

What is wrong with these codes?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your `else` block has no corresponding `if` block. [The return type of `main` is `int`, not `void`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main/4207223#4207223). You should use a `std::string` instead of a `char[11]`; `cin >> fname` is a gaping security bug (consider what happens if the user inputs more than ten characters).

Answer (score 6):

- in C++ it's `int main` instead of `void main`,
- you should use `std::string` instead of char arrays (safer, more convenient),
- for testing if a single character is a letter, there are functions defined in `<cctype>`, like `isalpha()`,
- you cannot have an "else" without an "if".

Try to draw a flow diagram for what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting a compilation error about the `else`.  The proper syntax for `else` is:

```
if (expression)
{  // this is done is expression is true
}
else 
{ // this is done if expression is false
}
```

You might also want a `break` statement in your else once you move it into the while.