# Returning ints versus void

Tags: c++, function, program-entry-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the proper declaration of main?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main)

A little while ago I took a course on c++ algorithms. We used visual studio in the classroom and sometimes when writing the main function we would declare it void main() { as opposed to int main(){return 0;} . This worked fine although I knew it normally you should use int. Just recently I tried compiling the same code from the class in netbeans in linux. This time, it would not accept the main function to be declared void. Why is it that the g++ compiler requires the main function to be declared an int? Sorry if this is a silly question.

Comment: This is discussed in [What is the proper declaration of main?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main)  (There is a lot of information in that post.  To summarize, the return type of `main()` in both C and C++ must be `int`.  Visual C++ happens to support `main()` with a return type of `void` as a nonstandard, implementation-provided language extension).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard says that it needs to be `int main()` (emphasis here on the return type, not the arguments).

`void main()` is not standard, and as such bound to break on various platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I remember that every program has a return value, although I don't remember whether or not it just returns a certain number by default. In assembly, you can just say return, if I recall correctly, and not have to give a value.

Or it could just be that it's just not the standard for C++ compilers, like EboMike said.