# Learning C++: polymorphism and slicing

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Animal
{
public:
    virtual void makeSound() {cout << "rawr" << endl;}
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
public:
    virtual void makeSound() {cout << "bark" << endl;}
};

int main()
{
    Animal animal;
    animal.makeSound();

    Dog dog;
    dog.makeSound();

    Animal badDog = Dog();
    badDog.makeSound();

    Animal* goodDog = new Dog();
    goodDog->makeSound();
}
```

The output is:

```
rawr
bark
rawr
bark
```

But I thought that surely the output should be "rawr bark **bark** bark".  What's with the badDog?

---

Update: You may be interested in [another question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405634/learning-c-returning-references-and-getting-around-slicing).

Comment: I think you have some naming errors for your variables.

Comment: The code doesn't even compile as is. And `void main()` ??? Ew...

Comment: I can't understand why someone would downvote this question -- it's neither "unclear" nor "not useful". +1 to negate the downvote.

Comment: +1 for the cute doggy metaphore.

Comment: The guideline "Make non-leaf classes abstract" would prevent this surprise.

Comment: And another +1 for posting a complete, minimal example that illustrates the problem.  Which is exactly what we always ask for.

Comment: The -1 is for posting code that doesn't even compile, and failing to fix it even when this has been pointed out.

Comment: oops... code should be fixed now.  Sorry. (Now I want my point Paul!)

Comment: @John: It's almost fixed. The correct return type of `main` is `int` (you can read more than you ever wanted to know about the `main` function in ["What is the proper declaration of main?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main/4207223#4207223)

Comment: @James - No.  The *standard* return for main is int.  An implementation is free to accept any signature and provide other entry points.  If this was comp.lang.c++ where people get smacked for non-standard code and questions then you'd have a point.  That isn't the SO way though.

Comment: @Noah:  That's been the SO way for as long as I've been here.  Questions tagged only [c++] are assumed to be in Standard C++ with no platform-specific extensions.

Comment: Haha, I love the return sqrt(-1)! :)

Comment: @Noah: No. The `main` function "shall have a return type of type `int`, but otherwise its type is implementation defined." (N3225 3.6.1/2)

Comment: Though technically your comment is correct where you say "an implementation is free to accept any signature," since the return type of a nontemplate function is not part of its signature.  :-)

Comment: @John Berryman.  If you are struggling to see what the payoff is for learning concepts such as this in C++, please take a look at design patterns (at a later stage when your familiar with concepts such as pollymorphism).  Most of the patterns are only possible due to the concepts you are currently trying to learn.  Please see here for C++ implementations of patterns http://www.vincehuston.org/dp/.  Also, if you want a good text book on this stuff please get http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Objects-Comparative-Presentation-Oriented/dp/0471268526.

Comment: @David - The payoffs are obvious.  I actually have a good understanding of polymorphism and its uses in design pattern, it's just that I come from a Java background and C++ treats values and references very different.

Comment: Since you come from a Java background, I'd strongly recommend a good C++ textbook. C++ and Java differ on the most fundamental level: their object and memory models are completely and totally different and the idioms used in the two languages are likewise completely different. Introductory books can be tough to read as an experienced programmer because they are "boring" (yes, I know; I've been learning C# recently, and it's been a beating at times), but I'd argue it's very important, especially for C++, since it's very easy to write wrong, incorrect C++ code.

Comment: you should really rename Animal to Dinosaur :)

Comment: Nobody mentioned that it's leaking memory??

Comment: I replied to your slide with some interesting complements :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405634/learning-c-returning-references-and-getting-around-slicing

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This is a problem called "slicing."

`Dog()` creates a `Dog` object.  If you were to call `Dog().makeSound()`, it would print "bark" as you expect it to.

The problem is that you are initializing the `badDog`, which is an object of type `Animal`, with this `Dog`.  Since the `Animal` can only contain an `Animal` and not anything derived from `Animal`, it takes the `Animal` part of the `Dog` and initializes itself with that.

The type of `badDog` is always `Animal`; it can never be anything else.

The only way you can get polymorphic behavior in C++ is using pointers (as you have demonstrated with your `goodDog` example) or using references.

A reference (e.g., `Animal&`) can refer to an object of any type derived from `Animal` and a pointer (e.g., `Animal*`) can point to an object of any type derived from `Animal`.  A plain `Animal`, however, is always an `Animal`, nothing else.

Some languages like Java and C# have reference semantics, where variables are (in most cases) just references to objects, so given an `Animal rex;`, `rex` is really just a reference to some `Animal`, and `rex = new Dog()` makes `rex` refer to a new `Dog` object.

C++ doesn't work that way:  variables don't refer to objects in C++, variables are objects.  If you say `rex = Dog()` in C++, it copies a new `Dog` object into `rex`, and since `rex` is actually of type `Animal`, it gets sliced and just the `Animal` parts get copied.  These are called value semantics, which are the default in C++.  If you want reference semantics in C++, you need to explicitly use references or pointers (neither of these are the same as references in C# or Java, but they are more similar).

Comment: I will add that I have grossly oversimplified the comparison between the type systems of Java and C# and C++.

Comment: Why c++ object assignment doesn't copy the vptr together with the rest members, to get the poloymorphism in variable level?

Answer (score 11):

```
 Animal badDog = Dog();
    ad.makeSound();
```

When you instantiate a `Dog` and assign it by-value to an `Animal` variable, you [slice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) the object.  Which basically means you strip off all the `Dog`-ness from `badDog` and make it in to the base class.

In order to use polymorphism with base classes, you *must* use either pointers or references.

Answer (score -1):

You initialized badDog using the assignment operator. Thus Dog() was copied as Animal. The output of your program is correct. :)