# c++ member function binding

Tags: c++

I read one of the book which deals with the issues of member function binding in c++.

and it's giving the next example:

```
void Window::oops()  { printf("Window oops\n"); } 
void TextWindow::oops() { 
printf("TextWindow oops %d\n", cursorLocation);

Window      win; 
Window     *winPtr;
TextWindow *txtWinPrt = new TextWindow; 
win    = *txtWinPrt; 
winPtr =  txtWinPtr;
win.oops();     // executes Window version 
winPtr->oops(); // executes TextWindow or Window version;
```

I didn't understand why `win.oops` would executes window version? win is defined as Textwindow.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please add the class definition inheritance schema and use of virtual keyword may change the behavior of your exemple.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's a very good book. Maybe you could find a different one with some more useful examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403726/learning-c-polymorphism-and-slicing/4403759#4403759). If you assign to an object of the super-class, the information from the subclass is lost. The problem is this statement:

```
win    = *txtWinPrt;
```

Since you assign an object of a subclass (`TextWindow`) to an object of the super-class (`Window`), all the information of `TextWindow` that is not in `Window` is sliced away.

Comment: @Hassan: I added an explanation. A more detailed one can be found in the excellent answer I linked.

Comment: Thank you a lot. It helps me. The book mention the Slicing in two words, and I can't understand what it means.

Comment: Slicing has nothing to do with design it is a physical side effect of C++ semantics. It is also an ellusive concept to grasp especially when placed in the context of all the other features of C++ (multiple inheritance). A more sound answer should enhance understanding in as general a way as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
Window win
```

is an object of Window class. It should be pointer or reference to call derived class method with base class instance.

Answer (score 0):

Two things are needed for dynamic polymorphism using object orientation (which is what you are asking for).

1. Window and Textwindow need to implement the "is-a" relationship. (so, `class TextWindow : public Window {}`);
2. A virtual function is needed in a base-clase in order to get runtime polymorphism, generally a destructor if you cannot find a virtual function naturally. A virtual function causes the compiler to put down a v-table.

Without these two things, the compiler will not put a v-table down at callsites. The v-tables enables runtime polymorphism as function calls are indirected through it.

Alternatively you could resort to c-style function pointers, or something like boost::bind. But this defeats OO programming. I personally use a v-table very rarely.