# c++ inherit virtual functions

Tags: c++, function, virtual

ok say we have the following classes

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void taco()
    {
        cout << "Class A" << endl;
    }
};
class B: public A
{
    public:
    virtual void taco()
    {
        cout << "Class B" << endl;
    }
};
class C : public A
{
    public:
    void taco()
    {
        cout << "Class C" << endl;
    }
};
```

Now if I do this

```
A a = A();
B b = B();
C c = C();
a.taco(); //Class A
b.taco(); //Class B
c.taco(); //Class C
deque<A> aa = deque<A>();
aa.push_back(a);
aa.push_back(b);
aa.push_back(c);
for(int i=0;i<aa.size();i++)
    aa[i].taco();//All Class A
A r = B();
r.taco(); //Class A
```

Now you'll notice when I initialize A as B or C, it won't fire the functions from B or C. I was wondering if there was any way around this? I understand the concept that since the object is A it uses A's taco function, but I was just wondering if there was some trick to getting at the other functions. My project is fairly complicated, and I can't know all the classes that will override A(due to plugins overriding a class). Also, I kinda need to have the base virtual function have a body to add default behavior. Thanks.

Comment: Use pointers, and create the objects dynamically. Polymorphism in C++ requires the use of pointers or references. This should be covered in any C++ textbook - which one are you using?

Comment: Why not put that as the answer.

Comment: Neil may have wrote it as a comment, but treat it as an answer ;-)

Comment: `B::taco()` does not need the `virtual` qualifier.

Comment: @John: But you should still use it. And on `C::taco()`.

Comment: @Tomalak:  I completely disagree.  There is no need for this whatsoever.

Comment: @John: If I'm looking at `C`'s definition, I shouldn't have to happen to look at the corresponding definition of `A` to see that a function I might want to use is `virtual` [edit: though, alas, the mere ability to omit the keyword means I pretty much always have to anyway.. so there's a case there for not bothering]. Why would you ever omit it?

Comment: @Tomalak:  Clients of C should not have to care that `taco` is `virtual` if the class is designed properly.  Implementers of `C` are required to know the semantics of `A` in order to properly design `C` anyway.   Therefore, by no perspective that I can see is `virtual` required.  It may also not be desired, as `virtual` implies base-class semantics.  If `C` is in fact intended to be a leaf class, then the presence `virtual` implies semantics that don't exist.

Comment: BTW, it's just been brought to my attention that "I'm in a mood today" so maybe I'll just stop posting. :)

Comment: @John: I have nothing to say to that other than that, as a client of `C`, I most certainly care.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Learning C++: polymorphism and slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403726/learning-c-polymorphism-and-slicing)

Comment: @nbt One obscure book from the early 90's because when I tought myself c++ I was completely broke. Now out of that experience I make 70k a year with development. That was two years ago, amazing what you can get done in two years.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must store pointers in the `deque`, since polymorphism only works with reference & pointer types. When you insert those objects into the `deque`, copies are made of type `A`, "slicing" off the parts that made them `B` or `C` originally.

Similarly, `A r = B()` just creates a temporary `B` and copies the `A` part of it into an `A` called `r`.

BTW by `A a = A();` you might as well write `A a;`. They're not completely equivalent, but they do the same job here, and you likely meant for the simpler version.

```
A a;
B b;
C c;
a.taco(); //Class A
b.taco(); //Class B
c.taco(); //Class C

// With pointers and containers
deque<A*> aa;
aa.push_back(&a);
aa.push_back(&b);
aa.push_back(&c);
for (int i=0; i<aa.size(); i++)
    aa[i]->taco(); // Hurray!    

// With refs
B q;
A& r = q;
r.taco(); // Class B!
```

(Just remember that those objects `a`, `b` and `c` have automatic storage duration. The moment they go out of scope, if the `deque` still exists then all its elements are invalid pointers. You may want to employ dynamic allocation to further control the lifetime of the `A`, `B` and `C` objects.. but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.)