# Getting OOP right

Tags: c++

Ok, this is my problem. I have the following classes:

```
class Job {
   bool isComplete() {}
   void setComplete() {}
   //other functions
};

class SongJob: public Job {
   vector<Job> v;
   string getArtist() {}
   void setArtist() {}
   void addTrack() {}
   string getTrack() {}
   // other functions
};
// This were already implemeted
```

Now I want to implement a VideoJob and derived it from Job. But here is my problem. I also have the following function witch it was set to work only with SongJob:

```
void process(SongJob s)
{
// not the real functions
   s.setArtist();
   ..............
   s.getArtist();
   .............
   s.getArtist();
   ...............
   s.setArtist()
}
```

Here I just want it to show that the function uses only derived object methods. So if I have another object derived from Job, I will need to change the parameter to Job, but then the compiler would not know about thoose functions and I dont what to test for everyone what kind of object it is and then cast it so I can call the correct function.

So it is okay to put all the functions in the base class, because then I will have no problem, but I don't know if this is correct OOP, if one class deals with Songs and the other with videos, I thing good oop means to have 2 clases.

If I didn't make myself clear, please say so and I will try explaining better.
And in short words, I want to use polymorfism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is totally fine to put all the things that the classes `SongJob` and `VideoJob` have in common into a common base-class. However, this will cause problems once you want to add a subclass of `Job` that has nothing to do with artists.

There are some things to note about the code you have posted. First, your class `Job` is apparently not an [abstract base class](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/abcs.html). This means that you can have jobs that are just jobs. Not `SongJob` and not `VideoJob`. If you want to make it clear that there can not be a simple `Job`, make the base-class abstract:

```
class Job {
    virtual bool isComplete() = 0;
    virtual void setComplete() = 0;
   //other functions
};
```

Now, you cannot create instances of `Job`:

```
Job job; // compiler-error
std::vector<Job> jobs; // compiler-error
```

Note that the functions are now virtual, which means that subclasses can override them. The `= 0` and the end means that subclasses have to provide an implementation of these functions (they are [pure virtual member functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/abcs.html#faq-22.4)).

Secondly, your class `SongJob` has a member `std::vector<Job>`. This is almost certainly not what you want. If you add a `SongJob` to this vector, it will become a normal `Job`. This effect is called [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403726/learning-c-polymorphism-and-slicing). To prevent it, you'd have to make it a `std::vector<Job*>`.

There is much more to say here, but that would go to far. I suggest you get a good [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: so if SonjJob has a container to store songs and VideoJob one to store videos, these containers I should put them also in the base class ? I think the derived classes would not have any data left :)

Comment: I know about oop details, my problem is that i need to make this in c++ and also java, so I need to think in both languages :) But your explanation is very good. Thanks

Comment: @vBx: No, you can but these containers into the classes themselves. They are different, because the one stores *only* videos, while the other stores *only* songs. This is not a commonality, but a difference, so it does not belong into the base class.

Comment: OK, i made a base function add() and in the SongJob i add to the songs container and in the VideoJob i add to the videos container, i guess this is right

Comment: @vBx: It is only okay if you are fine with `SongJob` having `VideoJob` instances in its `v`.  If you aren't okay with that, you're going to have to make non-polymorphic `Add` methods on both `SongJob` and `VideoJob`, and you will never be able to access `Add` from the base type.  But you could still make a read-only `GetAllV` method on the base type...

Comment: @vBx: "the derived classes would not have any data left..."  That's not necessarily important.  Equally as important is that derived classes have different *implementation*.

Comment: About the last statement: changing std::vector<Job> to std::vector<Job*> would also work without slicing right? Because you do two steps with your new declaration: changing the type to a more specific one AND converting it to a pointer iso a value.

Comment: @KillianDS: That example was wrong, I fixed it. If it is a collection of the derived type, there is no need to make it a pointer. This is only required if you want a polymorphic collection.

Answer (score 3):

In your Base class `Job` you could add those methods as `virtual methods` so that a class deriving from `Job` may or may not override these specific methods.

In your `SongJob` class you override the methods and dont override them in `VideoJob`

In, `void process()` pass a pointer to Base class `Job`

```
void process(Job *s)
```

It will then call the appropriate methods depending on the adress of the objec s is pointing to which will be a `SongJob` object.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, you have to do two things to get polymorphism to work:

- Access polymorphic functions by a reference (`&`) or pointer (`*`) to a base type
- Define the polymorphic functions as `virtual` in the base type

So, change these from:

```
class Job {
  bool isComplete() {}
  void setComplete() {}
};

void process(SongJob s)
{
  // ...
}
```

To:

```
class Job {
  public: // You forgot this...
  virtual bool isComplete() { }
  virtual void setComplete() { }
};

void process(Job& s)
{
  // ...
}
```

If you can't define all the functionality you need inside `process` on your base class (if all the member functions you'd want don't apply to all the derived types), then you need to turn `process` into a member function on `Job`, and make it virtual:

```
class Job {
  public:
  virtual bool isComplete() { }
  virtual void setComplete() { }
  virtual void process() = 0;
};

// ...

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SongJob sj;
    Job& jobByRef = sj;
    Job* jobByPointer = new SongJob();

    // These call the derived implementation of process, on SongJob
    jobByRef.process();
    jobByPointer->process();

    delete jobByPointer;
    jobByPointer = new VideoJob();

    // This calls the derived implementation of process, on VideoJob
    jobByPointer->process();

    return 0;
}
```

And of course, you'll have two different implementations of `process`.  One for each class type.

People will tell you all sorts of "is-a" vs "has-a" stuff, and all sorts of complicated things about this silly "polymorphism" thing; and they're correct.

But this is basically the point of polymorphism, in a utilitarian sense:  It is so you don't have to go around checking what type each class it before calling functions on it.  You can just call functions on a base type, and the right derived implementation will get called in the end.

BTW, in C++, `virtual ... someFunc(...) = 0;` means that the type that function is defined in *cannot* be instantiated, and *must* be implemented in a derived class.  It is called a "[pure virtual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#Abstract_classes_and_pure_virtual_functions)" function, and the class it is defined on becomes "[abstract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_type)".

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the fact you're calling a process method on an object. You should have a method Process on the Job class and override this method in your derived classes.

Comment: well yes, this is what I did, but then i need to use typeid because a deirved object has a hasNewTrack() and the other derived object has hasnewClip() so the base class object doesnt have any of this, so I get error

Comment: Job.Process can be made pure virtual (no implementation). Then SongJob.Process will call hasNewTrack, but it will not call hasNewClip and VideoJob.Process will call hasNewClip, but it will not call hasNewTrack.

Answer (score 0):

use pure virtual functions:

```
class Job
{
virtual string getArtist() =0;
};
```