# Why do you need pointers in this situation?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, polymorphism

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Learning C++: polymorphism and slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403726/learning-c-polymorphism-and-slicing)

This is building off a question I asked before.
The classes look like this:

```
class Enemy
{
    public:
        void sayHere()
        {
            cout<<"Here"<<endl;
        }
        virtual void attack()
        {
        }
};

class Monster: public Enemy
{

    public:
        void attack()
        {
            cout<<"RAWR"<<endl;
        }

};
class Ninja: public Enemy
{

    public:
        void attack()
        {

            cout<<"Hiya!"<<endl;
        }
};
```

I am new to C++ and I'm confused as to why this will only work with pointers (both Ninja and monster are derived from Enemy):

```
int main()
{
    Ninja ninja;
    Monster monster;

    Enemy *enemies[2];

    enemies[0] = &monster;
    enemies[1] = &ninja;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        enemies[i]->attack();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why can't I instead do this?:

```
int main()
{
    Ninja ninja;
    Monster monster;

    Enemy enemies[2];

    enemies[0] = monster;
    enemies[1] = ninja;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        enemies[i].attack();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1, this question is actually pretty interesting. Of course I'm aware of why the second example doesn't work, but I'd be interested if someone knows why the second example isn't supported by the C++ standard at all (after all, "automatically" copying all required values from derived types shouldn't be that hard theoretically).

Comment: @heishe, it's called slicing, you can google it, it's kinda bad

Comment: Bonus points for "public Enemy" ;)

Comment: I like how friendlily the ninjas greet you as they strike.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a great question that hits at the heart of some of the trickier points of C++ inheritance.  The confusion arises because of the difference between **static types** and **dynamic types**, as well as the way that C++ allocates storage for objects.

To begin, let's discuss the difference between static and dynamic types.  Every object in C++ has a *static type*, which is the type of the object that is described in the source code.  For example, if you try writing

```
Base* b = new Derived;
```

Then the static type of `b` is `Base*`, since in the source code that's the type you declared for it.  Similarly, if you write

```
Base myBases[5];
```

the static type of `myBases` is `Base[5]`, an array of five `Base`s.

The *dynamic type* of an object is the type that the object actually has at runtime.  For example, if you write something like

```
Base* b = new Derived;
```

Then the dynamic type of `b` is `Derived*`, since it's actually pointing at a `Derived` object.

The distinction between static and dynamic types is important in C++ for two reasons:

1. Assignments to objects are always based on the static type of the object, never the dynamic type.
2. Invocations of virtual functions only dispatch to the dynamic type if the static type is a pointer or reference.

Let's address each of these in turn.

First, one of the problems with the second version of the code is that you do the following:

```
Ninja ninja;
Monster monster;

Enemy enemies[2];

enemies[0] = monster;
enemies[1] = ninja;
```

Let's trace through what happens here.  This first creates a new `Ninja` and `Monster` object, then creates an array of `Enemy` objects, and finally assigns the `enemies` array the values of `ninja` and `monster`.

The problem with this code is that when you write

```
enemies[0] = monster;
```

The static type of the lhs is `Enemy` and the static type of the rhs is `Monster`.  When determining how to do an assignment, C++ only looks at the static types of the objects, never the dynamic types.  This means that because `enemies[0]` is statically typed as an `Enemy`, it has to hold something precisely of type `Enemy`, never any derived type.  This means that when you do the above assignment, C++ interprets this to mean "take the `monster` object, identify just the part of it that's an `Enemy`, then copy that part over into `enemies[0]`."  In other words, although a `Monster` is an `Enemy` with some extra additions, only the `Enemy` part of `Monster` will be copied over into `enemies[0]` with this line of code.  This is called **slicing**, since you're slicing off part of the object and leaving behind just the `Enemy` base portion.

In the first piece of code that you posted, you have this:

```
Ninja ninja;
Monster monster;

Enemy *enemies[2];

enemies[0] = &monster;
enemies[1] = &ninja;
```

This is perfectly safe, because in this line of code:

```
enemies[0] = &monster;
```

The lhs has static type `Enemy*` and the rhs has type `Monster*`.  C++ legally allows you to convert a pointer to a derived type into a pointer to a base type without any problems.  As a result, the rhs `monster` pointer can be converted losslessly into the lhs type `Enemy*`, and so the top of the object isn't sliced off.

More generally, when assigning derived objects to base objects, you risk slicing the object.  It is always safer and more preferable to store a pointer to the derived object in a pointer to a base object type, because no slicing will be performed.

There's a second point here as well.  In C++, whenever you invoke a virtual function, the function is only called on the dynamic type of the object (the type of the object that the object really is at runtime) if the receiver is a pointer or reference type.  That is, if you have the original code:

```
Ninja ninja;
Monster monster;

Enemy enemies[2];

enemies[0] = monster;
enemies[1] = ninja;
```

And write

```
enemies[0].attack();
```

then because `enemies[0]` has static type `Enemy`, the compiler won't use dynamic dispatch to determine which version of the `attack` function to call.  The reason for this is that if the static type of the object is `Enemy`, it *always* refers to an `Enemy` at runtime and nothing else.  However, in the second version of the code:

```
Ninja ninja;
Monster monster;

Enemy *enemies[2];

enemies[0] = &monster;
enemies[1] = &ninja;
```

When you write

```
enemies[0]->attack();
```

Then because `enemies[0]` has static type `Enemy*`, it can point at either an `Enemy` or a subtype of `Enemy`.  Consequently, C++ dispatches the function to the dynamic type of the object.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 Especially for this bit, "because `enemies[0]` has static type `Enemy`, the compiler won't use dynamic dispatch to determine which version of the `attack` function to call".

Comment: +1. one of the best answers I have read on slicing.

Answer (score 16):

Without pointers, your enemies[] array represents a space on the stack sufficient to store two "Enemy" objects-- which means storing all their fields (plus perhaps overhead for a vtable pointer and alignment).  Derived classes of Enemy could have additional fields and therefore be larger, so it doesn't let you store a derived object of Enemy in the space reserved for an actual Enemy object.  When you do an assignment as in the example, it uses the assignment operator (in this case, defined implicitly)-- which sets the values in the left hand side object's fields to the values of the corresponding fields in the right hand side object, leaving the left-hand-side object's type (and so vtable pointer) unchanged.  This is called "object slicing" and is generally to be avoided.

Pointers are all the same size, so you can put a pointer to a derived object of Enemy in the space for a pointer to Enemy and use it just as if it were a pointer to a plain enemy object.  Since the pointer to a derived object points to an actual instance of the derived object, calls to virtual functions on the pointer will use the derived object's vtable and give you the desired behavior.

Comment: This is known as the slicing problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing

Comment: Yes, this is called 'slicing' an object, and it is bad!

Comment: But isn't the vtable stored in the same 'block' of memory as the Enemy object? Then, when I do `new Derived`, a pointer in the vtable is changed to direct to `Derived::attack` instead of `Enemy::attack`. Is the vtable stored somewhere else?

Comment: @Mat - I've expanded and clarified my response to reflect your (and others') comments.

Answer (score 3):

In c++, this is called slicing.

Enemy() creates a Enemy object. If you were to call Enemy().attack(), it would not print anything, because that method is empty.

The only way you can get polymorphic behavior in C++ is using pointers or references.

Answer (score 1):

Using pointers is how polymorphism is implemented in c++ (see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/)). You'll get a type mismatch error if you try to put a `monster` or a `ninja` object into an array of `enemies`. But "a pointer to a derived class is type-compatible with a pointer to its base class."

Answer (score 1):

That will give you an entirely different result.

In the first scenario with pointers, you'll have **Enemy** pointers that will point at your **Ninja** and **Monster** objects. The objects would be intact, and at runtime the attack() call would call the object's attack() method.

In the other scenario you have actual Enemy objects. When you'll assign the **Ninja** and **Monster** objects only the common members will be copied (the rest of the members that don't belong to Enemy will be lost).
Then when you'll call attack() it will be an **Enemy** attack() (Because they are **Enemy** objects)

Answer (score 1):

`Enemy enemies[2];` creates an array of objects of a concrete type (`Enemy`). That means, among other things, that all elements of that array have a known size.

How does that work with derived classes which might include other data? It doesn't.

On the other hand, given pointers, it doesn't matter at all. The pointer will point to "something" (the vtable plus data) and the virtual inheritance mechanism somehow figures out what's what and where's what. There may be the same functions, overloaded ones, additional data fields, it will still work.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning monster and ninja to your Enemy array will work, however, when you call the function attack on each one, it will call the base class's attack function. Why? First, when you assign the objects into the Enemy array, you're essentially typecasting those classes so when you interact with its objects, they act like Enemy's as opposed to what they originally were.

If you noticed, you declared your attack function in Enemy as virtual. What this allows is essential in polymorphism. By declaring that function as virtual, you allow subclassed objects (Monster and Ninja, for example) of your Enemy to determine, at run-time, which version of the function attack to use if an Enemy pointer is used. This allows you to use a generic Enemy pointer to access different subclassed objects and still correctly use the right function:

```
Enemy * ptr;
Enemy copy;
Monster m;

copy = (Enemy)m;
ptr = &m;

copy.attack(); // Calls Enemy's definition of attack, which is undefined.
ptr->attack(); // Even though this is an Enemy pointer, the Monster's definition of attack is used.
```

Answer (score 1):

By writing

```
enemies[0] = monster;
```

you are converting your Monster object to an Enemy object. Every derived class object can be converted automatically to a base class object. This is called object slicing. Once that conversion has happened the Enemy object no longer has any way of remembering that it once used to be a Monster object, it's just a plain Enemy object like any other. So when you call attack, you call Enemy::attack.

This issue doesn't arise in Java because in Java everything is a pointer automatically.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't supported because when you assign a superclass instance the value of a subclass instance, the subclass information not in the superclass is culled. Ergo, some methods - even polymorphic ones - which are subclass-dependent wouldn't work in all situations. The only general-purpose way to guarantee type-safety at compile time is to use the parent class's implementation.

Short version: instances of the parent class may have less state than child class instances, so operations on instances of the parent class have to assume they are those defined for the parent class. Pointers obviate this since child class instances with full state do exist.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is impossible (maybe very difficult and maybe can be done using pointers) to implement such functionality. The main reason is that base and derived objects can have different sizes `(sizeof(Enemy) != sizeof(Monster))`, and storing monsters in enemies you will just loose some data.