# For virtual functions, what happens when accessing certain methods when declared virtual and when not

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, object, virtual

For virtual functions, what happens when accessing certain methods when declared virtual and when not.

my idea:

if it is virtual, the calling instance will search its virtual function table for the function, if it is a base  instance pointer that point to a derived instance, the  derived instance’s virtual function implementation will be called. If it is not a virtual function, the calling instance’s function call be called.

Right ?

Answer (score 1):

From a language standard point of view, there's nothing more to say than what you probably already know: If a function is virtual, then calling it on any base class reference or pointer will cause the most derived actual function to be called.

That's it. All that matters is behaviour.

What you really seem to be after is how compilers implement this. Indeed, a vtable is the most popular way to implement virtual dispatch. It's essentially a list of function pointers which is maintained for each class that has virtual functions. (Remember that deriving from a class with virtual functions automatically makes those functions virtual again in the derived class.)

However, the way the compiler actually *calls* a function varies.

- If the function is not virtual, it is known at compile time and dispatched statically to the member function of the static class type on which it was called.
- If the function is virtual but the compiler can prove the dynamic type of a base reference/pointer at compile time, it may choose to call the function of the corresponding derived class directly.
- If the dynamic type cannot be inferred by the compiler, the function dispatch happens at runtime by looking up the function pointer of the actual (most derived) function in the vtable.

Example:

```
struct A {
  void foo();
  virtual void bar();
};
struct B : A {
  void foo(); // hides A::foo() -- very bad style
  void bar(); // automatically virtual!!
};

int main() {
  B x;
  A * a1 = &x;  // pointer-to-base;
  A * a2 = get_pointer();

  a1->foo(); // static dispatch to A::foo() (non-virtual function)
  a1->bar(); // dispatch to B::foo(), possibly resolved statically
  a2->bar(); // dynamically dispatched to whatever the most derived class is
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right.  If you call a `virtual` function through a base class pointer, the override will be called.  On the other hand, if you call a non-`virtual` function through a base class pointer, the base class function will be called.

The same holds true when calling through references instead of pointers.

One thing to be aware of when dealing with base class pointers is [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403726/learning-c-polymorphism-and-slicing/4403762#4403762).  If you do this:

```
Base* pb = new Der;
Base other = *pb;
```

`other` has sliced the object, and all the `Der`-ness has gone away.