# list of polymorphic objects

Tags: c++, list, stl, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I have a particular scenario below. The code below should print 'say()' function of B and C class and print 'B says..' and 'C says...' but it doesn't .Any ideas..
I am learning polymorphism so also have commented few questions related to it on the lines of code below.

```
class A
{
public:
// A() {}
    virtual void say() { std::cout << "Said IT ! " << std::endl; }
    virtual ~A(); //why virtual destructor ?
};

void methodCall() // does it matters if the inherited class from A is in this method
{
    class B : public A{
    public:
        // virtual ~B(); //significance of virtual destructor in 'child' class
        virtual void say () { // does the overrided method also has to be have the keyword  'virtual'
            cout << "B Sayssss.... " << endl; 
        }
    };
    class C : public A {
    public:
        //virtual ~C();
        virtual void say () { cout << "C Says " << endl; }
    };

    list<A> listOfAs;
    list<A>::iterator it;

    # 1st scenario
    B bObj; 
    C cObj;
    A *aB = &bObj;
    A *aC = &cObj;

    # 2nd scenario
    //  A aA;
    //  B *Ba = &aA;
    //  C *Ca = &aA; // I am declaring the objects as in 1st scenario but how about 2nd   scenario, is this suppose to work too?

    listOfAs.insert(it,*aB);
    listOfAs.insert(it,*aC);

    for (it=listOfAs.begin(); it!=listOfAs.end(); it++)
    {
        cout <<  *it.say()  << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    methodCall();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is called **slicing** and you should check this question: [Learning C++: polymorphism and slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4403726/1168156)

You should declare this list as a list of pointers to `A`s:

```
list<A*> listOfAs;
```

and then insert these `aB` and `aC` pointers to it instead of creating copies of objects they are pointing to. The way you insert elements into list is wrong, you should rather use `push_back` function for inserting:

```
B bObj; 
C cObj;
A *aB = &bObj;
A *aC = &cObj;

listOfAs.push_back(aB);
listOfAs.push_back(aC);
```

Then your loop could look like this:

```
list<A*>::iterator it;
for (it = listOfAs.begin(); it != listOfAs.end(); it++)
{
    (*it)->say();
}
```

Output:

```
B Sayssss....
C Says
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually *using* a container of naked pointers is a pandora's wasp nest, though, and any number of things can go wrong...

Comment: I agree. But in this case I consider it more appropriate to use naked pointers so that he better understands what's going there.

Comment: in the above scenario do i have to also take care of List elements once i used it.. Do i have to delete it or something ???

Comment: In this list there are references to automatic variables (`bObj` and `cObj`), so no. You don't delete it since you hadn't allocated it.

Answer (score 2):

Polymorphism of virtual class hierarchies only works through **references** or **pointers** to a base subobject:

```
struct Der : Base { /* ... */ };

Der x;

Base & a = x;

a.foo();   // calls Der::foo() from x
```

The function `foo` is dispatched polymorphically if it is a virtual function in `Base`; the polymorphism refers to the fact that while you are calling a member function of an object of type `Base`, the function that actually gets called may be implemented in the class `Der`.

Containers can only store elements of a fixed type. In order to store a polymorphic collection, you could instead have a container of pointers to the base class. Since you need to store the actual objects elsewhere, lifetime management is non-trivial and best left to a dedicated wrapper such as `unique_ptr`:

```
#include <list>
#include <memory>


int main()
{
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<Base>> mylist;

    mylist.emplace_back(new Der1);
    mylist.emplace_back(new Der2);
    // ...

    for (p : mylist) { p->foo(); /* dispatched dynamically */ }
}
```

Comment: 1 : What does this "Containers can only store elements of a fixed type." means ??
2 : "you could instead have a container of pointers to the base class"
Do you mean 'list<A *> listOfAs' instead of 'list<A> listOfAs;'

Answer (score 0):

`list::iterator it;
B bObj; 
C cObj;
A *aB = &bObj;
A *aC = &cObj;
listOfAs.insert(it,*aB);`

Do you not need to initialize "it" ?
I believe you should do it = listOfAs.begin(); before starting to insert.