# What's a naked pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, terminology

Observing [Naked Pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241680/list-of-polymorphic-objects) (see the first reply), the questions is pretty simple:

what is a Naked Pointer?

Comment: A real pointer, as opposed to a smart pointer.

Comment: @ildjarn, so what's a smart pointer? :)

Comment: @NickDandoulakis see talnicolas' comment

Comment: Sad, because I can't correct spelling mistakes here. The edit must contain at least 6 letters. But I don't want to add new letters. Strange. But why? :(

Comment: @kame: Discussion on that subject at http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77962

Comment: @talnicolas : ever heard of StackOverFlow...why not StackOverFlow..why google always ??..Bytheway, this world is so cruel :P, I thought lets see what people have to say on this topic and have already EARNED -1 point for this.

Comment: @MuhammadSalman Well the -1 tool-tip does say "This question does not show any research effort" and well... your question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's simple example:

```
#include <memory>

struct X { int a,b,c; };

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<X> sp(new X);
    X* np = new X;
    delete np;
}
```

`np` is pointer to object of type `X` - if you have dynamically allocated (`new` / `malloc`) this object, you have to `delete` / `free` it... simple pointer like `np` is called **"naked pointer"**.

`sp` is an object that holds a pointer to the managed resource, which means you can use it just like you would use `np`, but when there are no `shared_ptr` objects that own this resource, the resource is freed, so you don't have to `delete` it. **Smart pointers** take care of memory management, so you don't have to ;)

Comment: so a naked pointer is truly naked(i.e delete has to be enforce) only and only if it is dynamically allocated via new.

Comment: @MuhammadSalman: yes with one exception: if you allocate an array with `a = new int[5];` you should delete it like this: `delete[] a;`

Comment: You should deallocate objects just like you allocated them. Which means to use `malloc`/`calloc` with `free`, `new` with `delete` and `new []` with `delete[]`

Comment: Thankyou, after all NP is easy to grasp. I was confused because of one comment regarding NP in your reply to the post i mentioned in the question above.

Answer (score 15):

A "naked pointer" is a "plain" pointer, i.e. the thing that the Standard and whatever book on C++ call pointer. It's the usual "`T *`" (where `T` is the type of what the pointer points to).

The "naked" terminology came on to oppose them to *smart* pointers, which are classes that behave in many respects as pointers (usually they overload the operators `*`, `->` and in some cases `[]`).

Smart pointers are "smart" because they specify and enforce some ownership semantic, removing the "dumbness" of naked pointers: in facts naked pointers don't specify/know if they *own* the object they are referring to (e.g. if it must be deallocated when the pointer goes out of scope) and, even if with some naming convention it's known that some pointer owns the object if points to, the language doesn't enforce this, so, if a pointer goes out of scope and nobody manually released the pointed object (typically this happens if an exception is raised) you have a memory leak.

Smart pointers, instead, exploit the guarantees of the type system of C++ (copy constructor, assignment operator, guaranteed calls to destructor, ...) to establish and enforce some kind of ownership (typically: strict and nontransferable, strict but can be transferable to another smart pointer, shared between several smart pointers).

... that being said, there are tons of discussions about smart pointers on StackOverflow and on the Internet, I'm quite sure you'll be able to find more extensive discussions on smart pointers and why using naked pointers that own objects is usually a Bad Thing<sup>TM</sup> in a modern C++ program.

Answer (score 10):

A naked pointer (raw pointer, "dumb" pointer) is a C-style pointer `T*`. Contrast this with the "smart" pointers C++ offers (`std::shared_ptr<T>`, `std::weak_ptr<T>` and `std::unique_ptr<T>`).

Answer (score 4):

Smart pointers are preferred pointers in C++ because they offer better better memory management. They have extra information (counting the number of references, current ownership etc etc) along with the address of the object they point to. However, a naked pointer doesn't hold such extra informationand therefore can't delete the object they are pointing to after it's no longer used.