# How do I call an overloaded function from a function in the base class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, vector

I have a class (B) that inherits another class (A). I want to call a function from class A that has been overridden. I also want to be able to call the overridden function independent of what class inherited the base (say `class C : public A` , where I want to call C's version of the function.)

Here's an example

```
class A {

public:
    void callF();
    virtual void f() {};
};

class B : public A {

public:
    void f();
};

void A::callF()
{
    //FYI, I want to be able to call this without knowing what the super class is.
    f();
}

void B::f()
{
    std::cout << "I want this function to be called, but instead the default f() is called.";
}
```

**Edit:**
 In my real code, I have an `std::vector<A> aVector;`. Then I would call `aVector.push_back(B());`. If I called `aVector[0].callF();`, The default `a::f()` would be called. 
As answered below, I have a problem with slicing.

Comment: Please clarify your question a bit. You want to be able to call the overridden function f() when it is called from the base-class. In the example above, when you call f() in the class A, you want the overridden function in B to be called. Is that so?

Comment: That is right.
Also, say I implemented `class C` which inherits A. When I call `C c; c.callF()`, I would want it to call C's version of f().

Comment: The code you have given us does exactly what you ask for. If your program is behaving differently, the problem may lie in what you are **not** showing us. Please create a small, *complete* program that demonstrates the problem and paste that program into your question. http://sscce.org/

Comment: Where is your virtual inheritance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your construction:

```
vector_of_A.push_back( B() );
```

doesn't store a `B` in the vector. It constructs a `B`, then constructs an `A` from that, then stores **that** `A` in the vector. As a consequence, you experience slicing.

See this for more info:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4403759/8747

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct.

You may be getting the behavior you observed because your were calling f() or callF() from the constructor of A.  That's the only case I can think of where A::f() would get invoked instead of B::f().

Comment: That's a good point. I may have been calling it from the constructor, or I might be having problems calling it from a std::vector<A>. I'm calling it outside of the constructor, but It still calls A::f().

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me with this little test program:

```
int main()
{
    // Instantiate B, and reference it via a base class pointer.
    A* b = new B;

    b->callF();
    delete b;
}
```

Output:

```
I want this function to be called, but instead the default f() is called.
```

When calling a virtual member function within a base class member function, it's the derived member function that will be invoked.

Comment: Okay. I'm probably having trouble with something else. In my real code, I have a `std::vector<A> aVector;`. Then I would call `aVector.push_back(B());`. If I called `aVector[0].callF();`, The default `a::f()` would be called.
I should probably ask another question now.. Thanks for answering!

Comment: @sFuller Please read http://sscce.org, particularly the part that says, "Make sure the code you post displays the problem!"

Comment: Ah, your problem is a common one and is called **slicing**. I'm sure the other answerers will explain your problem faster than I can, as I don't have their fast ninja skills. Please edit your question and paste the comment you just posted here in my answer.