# C++ / Polymorphism / Virtual Functions / Why is my child class's function not being called?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, polymorphism

I looked around, and most questions deal with why you would use virtual, what polymorphism is and so on.  I am having a problem in my program and I want to know *WHY* the child function is not being called and how to actually *CALL* the child function in this situation.

I can emulate my problem:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class BaseA {
  public:
  BaseA(const std::string &n)
    : name(n)
  {
  }

  virtual void print() const
  {
    std::string str("");
    str += name;
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
  }

  protected:
  std::string name;
};

class BaseB : public BaseA {
  public:
  BaseB(const std::string &n, const std::string &v)
    : BaseA(n), value(v)
  {
  }

  void print() const
  {
    std::string str("");
    str += name;
    str += ' ';
    str += value;
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
  }

  private:
  std::string value;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<BaseA> vec;
  vec.push_back(BaseA("cat"));
  vec.push_back(BaseB("cat", "kitten"));

  for(BaseA &obj : vec)
    obj.print();

  return 0;
}
```

**Why is the output: cat cat?**
**How do I change the output to "cat cat kitten " using BaseB::print()?**

Comment: This is mostly very true @remyabel.  I'd like to point out in my defense, if you don't know the term is coined as SLICING, it's rather difficult to discover the correct question without showing it visually.

Comment: @Ben It's an automatic comment when you close vote. There's no offense intended.

Comment: @remyabel None taken.  Onwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by [rightføld](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27001245/c-polymorphism-virtual-functions-why-is-my-child-classs-function-not-be#comment42532528_27001245), you are victim of the slicing problem. However, since your question is tagged C++11, you can take advantage of `std::unique_ptr`.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseA>> vec;
vec.push_back(std::make_unique<BaseA>("cat"));
vec.push_back(std::make_unique<BaseB>("cat", "kitten"));

for(std::unique_ptr<BaseA>& obj : vec)
    obj->print();
```

Unfortunately `std::make_unique` was not added until C++14, you may choose to use `emplace_back` instead.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseA>> vec;
vec.emplace_back(new BaseA("cat"));
vec.emplace_back(new BaseB("cat", "kitten"));

for(std::unique_ptr<BaseA>& obj : vec)
    obj->print();
```

Comment: This answer is extremely helpful and solves my problem elegantly.  Thank you @remyabel.

Comment: When does the actual Slice happen?  Could you point that out in your answer possibly?  Is it the moment I push the Object onto the vector?

Comment: @Ben [Learning C++: polymorphism and slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403726/learning-c-polymorphism-and-slicing) may be illuminating (admittedly, it does a better job of explaining than the proposed duplicate.)

Comment: Thanks again @remyabel.  It does explain it much better I agree.  One really must remember how diverse C++ is and how close its syntax brings you to the machine.

Comment: Note:  the emplace version as specified can leak memory if emplace_back causes the vector to grow and there isn't enough memory.

Comment: If anyone plans on placing the objects in other vectors like I am, use std::shared_ptr instead of std::unique_ptr.