# QVariant custom classes polymorphism

Tags: c++, qt, qvariant

I have such a classes hierarchy:

```
class Base {
...
virtual QWidget* getEditor();
...
}

class Derived {
...
QWidget* getEditor() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
...
}
```

Both classes are registered via Q_DECLARE_METATYPE()

I'm getting instance of Base class from QVariant. Is it possible to get a **pointer** from QVariant to be able to invoke `getEditor()` from a Derived object?

I'm trying this atm but have no success:

```
if (index.data(Qt::EditRole).canConvert<Base>())
    return index.data(Qt::EditRole).value<Base>().getEditor(parent);
```

This snipper invokes Base class method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your base class' function `virtual` to enable polymorphism:

```
class Base {
...
virtual QWidget* getEditor();
...
}

class Derived {
...
QWidget* getEditor() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
...
}
```

Also, the way you have it now will cause [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403726/learning-c-polymorphism-and-slicing). You will need to acquire a pointer to `Derived`, and call the function on that pointer.

Comment: Edited my post. The question is how should I get pointer from QVariant::value<>()

Comment: @Eckler, to get the pointer from `QVariant` you must first store that pointer in the `QVariant`, so apparently you will have to change your code to store pointers, not objects.

Comment: Should I change Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Base) to Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Base*) is this case?

Comment: @Eckler, check something like this http://blog.bigpixel.ro/2010/04/storing-pointer-in-qvariant/