# Call derived class method when upcasted

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, overriding, upcasting

Right now I have a hierarchy as follows (`->` means parent of )

```
LSystem -> DLSystem -> Tree -> MonopodialTree
                            -> TernaryTree
```

And I have a function substitute which is defined in LSystem as follows and given a minimal implementation that `LSystem`, `DLSystem` and `Tree` use.

```cpp
virtual void substitute(Symbol s, std::vector<Symbol> &string);
```

Next, `MonopodialTree` and `TernaryTree` override the definition of substitute.

The problem arises because I want to have a `std::vector<Tree>` (with both Monopodial and Ternary) and iterate through it calling substitute for each one of them.

However, they both call `LSystem`'s substitute function instead of their own substitute function, what am I missing?

Comment: Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403726/learning-c-polymorphism-and-slicing). Basically you need pointers (e.g. `std::vector<Tree*>`) to avoid "object slicing" and to allow polymorphic behavior.

Comment: But then it fails when I try
MonopodialTree MT();
  Tree* T = &MT;

Comment: Try instead `MonopodialTree MT{}; Tree* T = &MT;` (note the `{}` instead of `()`), otherwise you declared a function, see [most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)

Comment: Then I get -> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc

Comment: With the code you posted I cannot help you debug your code. If you have a new question, please feel free to post a new question on Stack Overflow with a small but complete example and the full error message you are receiving.