# casting const to pass it to function that takes reference, what happens?

Tags: c++, casting, parameter-passing, const-cast

Can anyone tell me what happens here when passing to g in the main, is it static_cast?

```
int  & g (int&x){x++ ; return x ; } 
int main()
{

   const int a=5 ; 
   cout<<g((int&)a)<<endl; 
}
```

I am sure that no copy is made, since the code above is similar to the one below :

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        cout << "calling DEFAULT constructor\n\n";
    }
    A(A& Other)
    {
        cout << "Calling COPY constructor\n\n";
    }
    ~A()
    {
        cout << "Calling DESTRUCTOR\n\n";
    }
};

A& g(A& x)
{
    cout << "Inside g(A& x) \n\n";
    return x;
}

void main()
{
    const A a;
    g(const_cast<A&>(a));
}*/
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [The return type of `main` is always `int`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main/4207223#4207223).

Comment: @James : is what you say a standard? and is what I wrote non-standard? I'm waiting for your answer, and thanks alot :)

Comment: Just a last Question, what is the cast that applies if we make "a" a variable (not const)? thanks to anyone who answers :)

Comment: what is the reason for postfix `++` here? `int  & g (int&x){x++ ; return x ; }` why not `int  & g (int&x){return ++x ; }`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`static_cast` cannot remove constness.  This is a `const_cast`.

At runtime, this code (the first example) yields undefined behavior because you modify a const object.

Comment: Oops, I missed and wrote static_cast instead of const_cast, thanks alot for answering.

Comment: Is the undefined behavior definitely restricted to runtime? Or could a confirming compiler detect the violation and reboot the computer at compile time or something?

Comment: @Fred:  My understanding is that the expression only yields undefined behavior when it is evaluated.  So, I think the undefined behavior is restricted to runtime since there is no guarantee that the expression will be evaluated (e.g., another translation unit might have some static initialization that calls `std::exit()`, and since that would occur before `main()` is entered, the expression won't be evaluated.)

Comment: @Fred AFAIK undefined behaviour never excuses the compiler for crashing, launching zee missiles etc. **during compilation**. UB is a runtime phenomenon. The compiler could, though, detect the violation and emit a warning like "guaranteed to invoke undefined behaviour" (or "likely", etc., as appropriate), which the user may treat as an error.

Comment: Just a last Question, what is the cast that applies if we make "a" a variable (not const)? thanks to anyone who answers :)

Comment: I don't think the example with `A` has UB.

Comment: @Karl:  That's not correct.  This program exhibits undefined behavior:  `void main() { }`.  It would be perfectly acceptable for a compiler to crash or otherwise "misbehave" given that program.

Comment: @GMan:  No, the second example does not exhibit undefined behavior.  The first example certainly does.  (I read the question as being specifically about the first example; I'll clarify, thanks!)

Comment: @Mr.TAMER:  It would be a no-op static cast.

Answer (score 1):

A C-style cast is a vicious thing -- it will do everything that a `reinterpret_cast<>` or a `const_cast<>` will do. It's one of those "the power of a chainsaw with the ease-of-use of a chainsaw" things that C is rightly infamous for.

Using the C++-style casts will show that you need to do a `const_cast<>`, and then you should ask yourself why and find a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For int, there's no code needed to just pass the reference in.  Your cast lets it compile.

Comment: I know, but what cast does the compiler implicitly do?

Comment: It's certainly not reinterpret cast, as the bits of int are not the same as a reference.  It's also certainly not dynamic, because int isn't a class with virtual functions, and int& is not a superclass of int.  It can't be static, because you can't change constness.  So, if it's anything, it's const -- but nothing says an old-style cast has to do what a new style one does.

Comment: Actually, the C-style cast is specified in terms of static, const, and reinterpret cast, so it always performs some combination of those three (though, some of the behavior is slightly different, e.g. a C-style cast does not check base class accessibility before performing a static cast, so you can cast to a private base using a C-style cast but you can't using a static cast).

Comment: I think we're saying the same thing -- I say it's not definitely one of the new style, and you say it could be a combo or different behavior.