# int main(int argc, char** argv)

Tags: c++, arguments, program-entry-point

> **Duplicate:**
>   [What is the proper declaration of main?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main)

What do we mean by the arguments in this `main` function? What are they trying to tell us?

`int main(int argc,  char** argv)`

**UPDATE:** And, is the preceding line of code similar to this `int main(int argc,  char* argv[])`? If so, how can we say that `char** argv` is similar to `char* argv[]` as they don't look similar from an *array* point of view?

How is it compared with `int main()` which does not have any arguments?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `argc` parameter is the number of command line options specified, including the executable name, when the executable was invoked.  The individual command line options are found in the `argv` array, which is `NULL` terminated (the name and path used to invoke the executable is in `argv[0]`).

The difference between the two versions is simply if you want to parse command line arguments or not - if you are not interested in them then you can ignore them using the second form.

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function#C_and_C.2B.2B) offers a good explanation. The first parameter gives you the number of command line arguments, and the second gives you the actual arguments.

Answer (score 4):

They represent the command line parameters.

argc is the number of command line parameters, including the name of the executable.
argv is an array of null-terminated strings, where `argv[0]` is the command line parameter, and `argv[i]` is the ith parameter after that, `argv[argc-1]` being the last one and `argv[argc]` is actually well defined and a NULL pointer.

Thus:

`foo bar baz`

on the command line will have `argc`=3, `argv[0]`="foo" `argv[1]`="bar" `argv[2]`="baz" `argv[3]` = NULL

Note that there is no special attachment placed for "flag" arguments.

`grep -i foo bar.cpp bar.h`

would have 4 arguments (argc=5 including grep itself), -i being one of them and this would apply even if the next parameter was a "value" attached to the flag.

Note if you did a wildcard

`grep -i foo *`

in UNIX at least, the * would be expanded before the call into grep and thus each file that matched would be an argument.

Incidentally

`char** argv` and `char* argv[]`

do the same thing.

Also while the standard says you must use one of these signatures (you shouldn't even add in any consts) there is no law you have to use those two variable names, but it is so conventional now that they are pretty much universal. (i.e. you could use `argCount` and `argValues` if you want).

Comment: I think you mean `argc =3` not `argc =2`.

Answer (score 2):

argc gives you the number of arguments and argv gives you those arguments. The first one is the path to the .exe used to run your program, the following ones are arguments the caller of your .exe provided on the command line like this:

```
my.exe arg1 arg2
```

Whereas

```
int main() {}
```

just ignores the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

argv is an array holding the commandline parameters passed to the application. argc tells you the number of elements contained in that array.