# c++ ifstream undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am in Visual Studio and am getting 'ifstream undeclared identifier' with this code (same for ofstream)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
void main()
{
    ifstream infile("file.txt");
    ofstream outfile("out.txt");
}
```

do I need to include something else?

Comment: [The correct return type for `main` is `int`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main/4207223#4207223)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to scope it. Use `using namespace std;` or preface `ifstream` and `ostream` with `std::`

For example, `std::ifstream`

Currently, the compiler does not know where these structures are defined (since they are declared/defined within the `std` namespace). This is why you need to scope your structures/functions in this case.

Comment: Or add `using std::ifstream; using std::ofstream;` above where you use them.

Comment: @rach if this is the answer, make sure to mark it so. Click the check mark underneath the up and down arrows.

Answer (score 6):

You need to reference the standard namespace (std).  Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
void main()
{
    std::ifstream infile("file.txt");
    std::ofstream outfile("out.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
using namespace std;
```

instead of prefixing everyline with std::

Comment: Always pay attention to hint people to where exactly they can use "using namespace". It's alright inside your .cpp source, but could be horrible in the header.