# Array homework question need help

Tags: c++

Here is the question: 
     write a complete function definition for a function named findLargest that accepts as array of int as a parameter and accepts the array size as another parameter. The function should use a return statement to return the largest value in the array.

here is my rough code:

```
int findLargest()

{

    int size;

    cout << "Enter size of array" << endl;
    cin >> size;

    int i;
    int numArray [size];
    {
        for (i = 1; i < size; index++);
        {
            cout << "Enter " << i << "number" << endl;
            cin >> numArray [i];
        }
        }
int findLargest = numArray[1]

    int t;
        for (t = 2; t < 2 size ; index++);
        {
            if numArray[t] < findLargest 
            {
                findLargest = numArray[t];
            }
        }
    cout << "Your highest number is " << findLargest;
}
```

if anyone could help with the correct solution that would be great.

Comment: What is the problem? What errors/wrong results do you get?

Comment: [The correct return type for `main` is `int`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main/)

Comment: I do know i will not be using void main in my final question unless that is required for a complete function definition.

Comment: the problem is it wont compile correctly

Comment: For one thing, you didn't follow the directions. The assignment is asking for you to make a function that will return this value. AKA `int largestValue = MyFunction(numArray, 10);`

Comment: @Tejes- then what is needed to be done to the code to make it follow the directions.

Comment: @CLM: **read** the directions. They specifically state the function name. Go from there.

Comment: in the question im not too sure what array of int being a parameter means.

Comment: @Probs: In that case you need to go back and repeat the earlier parts of the course (or book). It should have been covered when you first learned about  functions.

Answer (score 4):

You could start with writing the function `findLargest(Your parameters here)` first and then call that function with a preinitialized array (e.g. `int myArray[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,0}; findLargest(myArray, 10)`) to test if it works. With that, you wouldn't need to read the content of the array from standard input and focus on the problem from your assignment instead.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, you can't do this:

```
int numArray [size];
```

as array dimensions must be compile-time constants, although if you are using GCC it may compile. Instead, investigate the use of the standard C++ feature, [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/).

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking for user input for the size of the array, you would need to create a dynamic array.

```
int size = 0;
cin >> size;

int *a = null; //could use any data type
a = new int[size];
```

before the program ends,

```
delete a[];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the parameters right yet.

> write a complete function definition
>   for a function named findLargest that
>   accepts as array of int as a parameter
>   and accepts the array size as another
>   parameter.

```
int findLargest(int theArray[], int size);
```

Next, you have to figure out how to iterate over the entire array:

```
for(int i=0; i<size; ++i)
```

Next, figure out if each element is the biggest one:

```
int max = theArray[0];
if (theArray[i] > max)   max = theArray[i];
```

When done, return the biggest value you found.

```
return max;
```

Then, combine all the parts together:

```
int findLargest(int theArray[], int size)
{
    int max = theArray[0];

    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i)
    {
        if (theArray[i] > max)   max = theArray[i];
    }

    return max;
 }
```

---

If you wish to go futher, test your function.

```
int main(void)
{
    int testA[6] = {4, 10, 3, 6, 5, 9};  // Answer should be 10.
    int testB[5] = {-8, -5, -1, -7, -6}; // Test of negative numbers.
    int testC[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};         // Test of zero and repeating numbers.

    cout << "Largest in A is " << findLargest(testA, 6);
    cout << "Largest in B is " << findLargest(testB, 5);
    cout << "Largest in C is " << findLargest(testC, 4);
}
```

Comment: not a big deal but you can save on one iteration if start on `i=1`, also perhaps handling size = 0 case, but perhaps it's assumed valid input with size >= 1

Comment: While you can save one iteration, the poster is clearly a student and I don't want to confuse him by even hinting that C-arrays might start at 1.  going from 0 to <size is the most common way to iterate a full array.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the assignment is pretty clear that you must define a function for this task, and can't do it inside `main()`:

```
int findLargest(int* array, int size)
{
    int largest = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > largest)
            largest = array[i];
    }

    return largest;
}

int main()
{
    int my_array[9] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 50, 6, 7, 8 } ;

    cout << "* Largest: " << findLargest(my_array, 9) << endl;    
}
```