# Styles of main functions in C

Tags: c, coding-style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the proper declaration of main?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main)

I am working on my C skills and I have noticed that

> int main( int argc, char *argv[] )

and

> return (EXIT_SUCCESS)

instead of

> int main() and return 0

Why is this?

Comment: Two questions are asked here, though.

Comment: @ChristianJonassen: And the FAQ question also discusses returning from `main()`.

Comment: You're right. This question is a duplicate.

Comment: I beg to differ (so I think that this question is not a duplicate of the one about C++ `main()` functions). The other question is specifically about C++ and has definite differences from the equivalent answer for C (most notably, the C standard does allow the return type of `main()` to be other than `int` - see my answer - whereas C++ categorically does not).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are going to ignore the argument list, it is reasonable and sensible to use:

```
int main(void) { ... }
```

The standards bless this usage, as well as the one with arguments.  You get a warning from GCC if you compile with `-Wstrict-prototypes` and don't include the `void`, so I write the `void`.  C++ is different here.

As for `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`, there seems to be little benefit to it in general; I continue to write `return 0;` at the end of a `main()` function, even though C99 permits you to omit any return there (and it then behaves as if you wrote `return 0;`).

> ISO/IEC 9899:1999
>
> §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup
>
> ¶1 The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no
>   prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no
>   parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be
>   used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent;<sup>9)</sup> or in some other implementation-defined manner.
>
> <sup>9)</sup> Thus, `int` can be replaced by a typedef name defined as `int`, or the type of `argv` can be written as
>   `char ** argv`, and so on.
>
> §5.1.2.2.3 Program termination
>
> ¶1 If the return type of the `main` function is a type compatible with `int`, a return from the
>   initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value
>   returned by the `main` function as its argument;<sup>10)</sup> reaching the `}` that terminates the
>   `main` function returns a value of 0. If the return type is not compatible with `int`, the
>   termination status returned to the host environment is unspecified.
>
> <sup>10)</sup> In accordance with §6.2.4, the lifetimes of objects with automatic storage duration declared in `main`
>   will have ended in the former case, even where they would not have in the latter.
>
> §7.20.4.3 The exit function
>
> ¶5 Finally, control is returned to the host environment. If the value of status is zero or
>   EXIT_SUCCESS, an implementation-defined form of the status successful termination is
>   returned. If the value of status is EXIT_FAILURE, an implementation-defined form
>   of the status unsuccessful termination is returned. Otherwise the status returned is
>   implementation-defined.

*Aside: Note that §5.1.2.2.3 clearly indicates that the C standard allows an implementation to permit return types for `main()` other than `int` (unlike the C++ standard, which expressly forbids a return type other than `int`).  However, as [Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366377/jens-gustedt) rightly points out, a non-`int` return type from `main` is only allowed if the implementation explicitly documents that it is allowed, and the documentation will probably place limits on what is allowed.*

Comment: +1, but perhaps one should add that the property of `main` not returning `int` is "implementation specific". That is that first of all it is not the user who chooses the return type by the compiler producer, and second this must be clearly specified in the compiler documentation.

Answer (score 1):

`int main (int argc, char * argv [])` is for when you want to take command line arguments.

`EXIT_SUCCESS` is just a `#define` that's more descriptive than `0`.

Answer (score 1):

`int main( int argc, char *argv[] )` allows the user input arguments at the execution of the program, i.e., that text you write in the console after the program name.

`return (EXIT_SUCCESS)` is in case an O.S. doesn't expect 0 as a value of successful exit: it would be any other value, but in most cases, EXIT_SUCCESS equals 0.

Comment: Returning 0 from main or calling `exit(0)` has to be interpreted as a successful exit, even if the value returned to the calling environment does not normally treat 0 as success (in that case, 0 gets mapped to something that will be treated as success).  See the quotes from the C99 standard in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Operating Systems can differ in how a program indicates successful operation.  The macro `EXIT_SUCCESS` ideally expands to a value appropriate for the system the program is compiled for.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status

Answer (score 1):

(The two things you ask have nothing to do with each other.)

To answer your first question:
Having int main() just means that the program is not accepting command line arguments.
When it takes the two arguments, argc is the argument count (it will always be greater than or equal to one, since the first argument will be the path or name of the program itself), and argv is the list of arguments.

To answer your second question:
EXIT_SUCCESS is *guaranteed* to be interpreted as success by the underlying operating system.