# C++ exam, who gets the first one correct?

Tags: c++, types, program-entry-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the proper declaration of main?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main)

I just attended my first c++ exam.
First question was

> **int main(◊, char ** argv)**
> Which one of the following suggestions will not work (as first formal parameter substitute for ◊):
>
> ```
>     a) char argc
>     b) int argc
>     c) double argc
>     d) bool argc
> ```

The answer counts 2% in a 4 hour purely handwritten individual exam.
All tools are allowed, accept any programmable device or any means of communication
Who can get this right :)?

Comment: Have you paraphrased, or is that the actual question? If it is, then it is quite badly formuulated.

Comment: Question needs either to specify an implementation or to ask which one *will* work. One of them is guaranteed by C++, so it's entirely up to the implementation whether it permits the others, and if so what happens. Plenty of the people who write these exams know C++ less well than plenty of people on SO, so I think that how to pass exams in "C++-stupid" isn't really on topic for the site.

Comment: @juanchopanza && Steve Jessop. That is the full question. It was originally asked in the Danish language, but the translation to English is pretty accurate.

Comment: @user1361521: I won't downvote you, but please send a "-1" to the examiners.

Comment: I would give 0 marks to whoever set the question, unless the Danish equivalent of "will not work" isn't totally ambiguous.

Comment: This question seriously needs to define what *will not work* means. There's *always* a way to get it to "work", involving dirty hacks, but it *works*. Meh.

Comment: Or if the question allows you to check multiple answers, and the Danish phrase translated here as "which one of these" could also be understood as "which of these".

Comment: :)... Only 1 specific answer is supposed to be the correct one.

Comment: The term "will not work" is just as vague in the danish form.

Answer (score 7):

Define what "works" means. Any of those *might* work, but a valid, standard-compliant, well-formed C++ program has either of the following signatures:

```
int main()
int main(int argc, char** argv)
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

So a), c) and d) are wrong.

Comment: And I think using the clue-stick(2x4) on anyone using a) c) or d) should be allowed. Technically on a platform where sizeof(char) == sizeof(int) a) could work just fine, but I would still prefer not seeing it at all, ever.

Comment: @r_ahlskog so you're saying UB is fine, as long as it works as expected?

Comment: I said "could work" and "prefer not seeing it at all, ever", maybe "would not explode every odd day of the week" and "slap them around a bit with the stick, just to be sure" would have been better. These questions where schools push UB really turns my stomach.

Comment: Is it UB? I thought it was implementation-defined which signatures are supported for `main` (other than that the return must be `int`). I sort of took it as read that the meaning of any additional signatures is also implementation-defined rather than UB. Of course, some implementations are slack to the point of non-conformance, because neither compiler nor linker actually checks that `main` has a supported signature.

Comment: @SteveJessop the UB comment was just a analogy, I wasn't implying having a different signature is UB. Just saying that even if something appears to work, it doesn't make it OK.

Comment: Possibly there's a technical difference between "working fine" and "being fine". Things that work fine but aren't fine are the sneakiest bugs!

Comment: @Steve Jessop. I agree. The question however, demands only 1 specific answer to be correct.

Comment: @SteveJessop oh yeah - unlucky it works fine :)

Comment: The signatures of `main` are implementation defined; except for the two required ones, the only requirement is that they all return `int`.  _If_ the program uses a signature of `main` which isn't supported, I think that a diagnostic is required; from a QoI point of view, it is certainly required.  So b) is guaranteed, and a), c) and d) are implementation defined, but will either fail to compile or will work.

Answer (score 3):

Define "will not work" ?

```
int main(char argc, char ** argv)
{
    printf("%d\n", argc);
    return 0;
}

./a.out 1 2 3
Output: 4

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    printf("%d\n", argc);
    return 0;
}

./a.out 1 2 3
Output: 4

int main(double argc, char ** argv)
{
    printf("%d\n", *(int*)&argc);
    return 0;
}

./a.out 1 2 3
Output: 4

int main(bool argc, char ** argv)
{
    printf("%d\n", argc);
    return 0;
}

./a.out 1 2 3
Output: 4
```

Comment: +1: for breaking the rules of the exam and using a programmable device :)

Comment: @Cicada  - Regarding "Will not work": Your guess is as good as mine. Which compiler are you using? In Xcode, I have only managed to compile option b).

Comment: Using g++ 4.5.2, everything compiled (with a warning on a, c, d though) and everything ran correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the question is asking **which one will not work**. It would have to be `double` all the others are integers.

I believe this would be the *correct* answer because you can't index an array with anything other than an integral value. But that assumes that you actually want to index the `argv` array.

But what a bad question to ask on a C++ exam.

Comment: It is indeed "which one will not work" - Only choosing exactly 1 option will qualify as an answer. Can you explain why you would argue the double? To me they all have the same functionality, as long as main() is called with no more arguments than argc has room for.

Answer (score 0):

"int argc" is the correct usage. argc represents the number of parameters passed to the main. So its only int.