# char **argv[] segfaults when trying to get input from the command line

Tags: c++, input, argv, argc

I'm trying to do the most basic of things and am hitting a brick wall. I'm trying to read in a file name from the command line to use later in my program, but I can't even seem to extract the name from argv[]. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv[]){
    cout << "argc = " << argc << "\n\n";
    cout << "Filename: " << argv[1] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I'm testing it on inputs that supply an argument of course, since there's no error checking. Here's what I get when I run the program:

```
./a.out testfilename
```

*

```
argc = 2

Filename: 0x7fff56e41d30
```

Now I understand argv[1] is a pointer to an array of chars, so this output makes sense. However, if I make the following change,

```
cout << "Filename: " << argv[1] << "\n";
```

to

```
cout << "Filename: " << *argv[1] << "\n";
```

in an attempt to dereference argv[1] to pull out the actual string, I get a segmentation fault..

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the proper declaration of main?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
```

but not

```
int main(int argc, char **argv[]){
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, wouldn't have noticed myself. Works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

That should be:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
                        ^ only one * here
```