# LoopFillZerobss has an undefined reference to main

Tags: c++, linker, program-entry-point, bare-metal, stm32f4discovery

I am compiling a c++ application for the STM32F4 microcontroller. 
All my code compiles successfully, but the link step fails with the 
following error:

```
/tmp/ccGj7Wge.o: In function `LoopFillZerobss':
(.text.Reset_Handler+0x32): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am familiar with typical cause for undefined reference to main errors, 
that is, trying to compile an application without a main present at all. 
However, I do have a main.cpp, and naturally, a main function within it. 
It compiles to main.o and this is linked in with the other object files created
during compilation.

I am cross-compiling onto the STM32F407 and I'm running bare metal.

Anyone have any insight into this or seen this error before? The only place I see the LoopFillZerobss
function is in the assembly startup file for the board.

Comment: So, you haven't got a `main` in your code? The `LoopFillZerobss` is presumably part of the initialization code before `main` - filling block-storage-section with zero is part of the initialization in C and C++, since global variables need to be set to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things to check:

- Make sure you declare `main` correctly.  For example, `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`, and not `void main(void)`.  This Stack Overflow article does a great job:  [What is the proper declaration of main?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main)
- Make sure you haven't accidentally wrapped `main` in a `namespace`.
- If you have an exceptionally quirky C++ compiler, you *may* need to mark `main` as `extern "C"`, but to be quite honest, I've never seen tools that needed that.

You should be able to see what symbols got defined by your `main.o` by running a tool such as `nm` on it.  (At least, UNIX-style tool chains, such as the GNU tool chain, offer an `nm` tool.)  `nm` will list the set of symbols defined by your executable.  You should see `main` listed as-is.

For example, on my Linux box, `int main(void) { }` in an otherwise empty .cpp file results in the following output from nm:

```
$ nm main.o
                 U __gxx_personality_v0
0000000000000000 T main
```

If I wrap `main` in a namespace (in this case `namespace fred`), I get a mangled name like this:

```
$ nm main.o
0000000000000000 T _ZN4fred4mainEv
                 U __gxx_personality_v0
```

Notice the extra gobbledegook around the name `main`.  You shouldn't see such gobbledegook in your `nm` output.

You should be able to see if you're correctly declaring `main` and not accidentally dropping it into a namespace.  Once you get that sorted, then the initialization routine `LoopFillZerobss` should be much happier.

Comment: Thank you! I had my main wrapped in a namespace, now everything works correctly!