# Error 1 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
void myswap(T & tmp1, T & tmp2)
{    
    T temp;
    temp = tmp1;
    tmp1 = tmp2;
    tmp2 = temp;
    return;
}

main()
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 20;
    double p = 10.9, q = 23.36;
    char s = 'o', t = 'u';

    myswap(x, y);
    cout << "x=" << x << "and y=" << y << endl;

    myswap(p, q);
    cout << "p=" << p<< "and q=" << q << endl;

    myswap(s, t);
    cout << "s=" << s << "and t=" << t << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I use visual studio 2013. when i run this code the compiler gives me the message "Error: missing type specifier - int assumed. C++ does not support default int".

Comment: **Please** avoid using tabs. They wreak havoc on everything.

Answer (score 4):

Function main shall have return type int that is

```
int main()
```

Answer (score 4):

Like the friendly message says, it is not main() but
int main()
Or 
int main(void)
Or
int main(int argc, char* argv[])

See also [What is the proper declaration of main?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main)