# Initialize/set char *argv[] inside main() in one line

Tags: c++, program-entry-point, argv

I want to initialize/set `char *argv[]` inside the `main()` so that I can use `argv[1], argv[2]...` later in my program.

---

Up to now, I know how to do this in two ways:

1. For `int main()`, use one line as:

   ```
   int main()
   {
       char *argv[] = {"programName", "para1", "para2", "para3", NULL};
   }
   ```

   Note that, using `NULL` in the end is because the pointers in the `argv` array point to C strings, which are by definition `NULL` terminated.
2. For `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`, I have to use multiple lines as:

   ```
   int main(int argc,char* argv[])
   {
       argv[0] = "programName";
       argv[1] = "para1";
       argv[2] = "para2";
       argv[3] = "para3";
   }
   ```

My question is that how can I combine these two methods together, i.e. use only one line to initialize it for `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`? Particularly, I want to be able to do like this (*this will be wrong currently*):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    argv = {"programName", "para1", "para2", "para3", NULL};
}
```

How can I be able to do this?

---

**Edit**: I know `argv[]` can be set in `Debugging Command Arguments`. The reason that I want to edit them in `main()` is that I don't want to bother to use `Debugging Command Arguments` every time for a new test case (different `argv[]` setting).

Comment: Strange idea. Your case 2 has a good chance to crash the program. argc and argv should be read-only.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main This link is better

Comment: Maybe you should describe what your larger goal is.  I suspect there might be a different approach that will work for you (though I'm not really sure I really understand the question, so I might be wrong).

Comment: @AlexFarber Although it's read only, I can still use new value in the `mani()` scope.

Comment: @herohuyongtao Why would it be readonly?

Comment: @remyabel I mean `argc` is read-only. Actually, I need to set `argc` as well. Deleted already as not relevant to this question.

Comment: This is very clearly an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). The variables `argc` and `argv` (or whatever you name them) are local to `main()` and you can do anything you want with them. The actual command-line parameters are read-only in standard C++, and if they can be accessed in a different way, it's through the OS API. What is it you're trying to solve by modifying the arguments?

Comment: If you're using C++, don't muck with argc/argv directly:  use a `std::vector<std::string>`.  You can easily initialize such a vector from argc and argv (via `std::vector<std::string> const args(argv, argv + argc);`) or you can initialize it yourself with whatever strings you choose if you want to use a set of known strings at runtime.  If you're learning C++, I'd recommend this approach.  It's much safer, harder to screw up, and requires fewer asterisks.

Comment: @Angew The reason that I want to edit them in main() is that I don't want to bother to use Debugging Command Arguments every time for a new test case (different argv[] settings).

Comment: @herohuyongtao This is a bad idea. Why not write a script that executes your program correctly instead of **modifying the tested code** every time you want to test something?

Comment: @arne Yes, it seems a bad idea in practice. But I want to be able to edit it during debugging.

Comment: @herohuyongtao: If you modify `argv` in main, it'll be only at compile-time, your hands are tied at debug time even then.

Comment: @legends2k What do you mean by `only at compile-time`?

Comment: I mean if you assign another string array to `argv` say like Emilio's solution, wouldn't you have to recompile it every time you change `n_argv`? If yes, then how does it help you debug, since every time you need a different string, you'll've to modify `n_argv`, compile and run the program. Correct?

Comment: Also, most debuggers are able to assign new values to variables during debug-time. Not sure about C-Strings though.

Comment: @legends2k Yes. But without this, how can I debug my program by adding some `breakpoints` for different test cases?

Comment: @herohuyongtao: See the answer I've just posted where you don't need to worry about setting breakpoints and modifying variables on-the-fly.

Comment: "Note that, using NULL in the end is because the pointers in the argv array point to C strings, which are by definition NULL terminated." – that has precisely **nothing** to do with the strings being NUL- (and **not** "NULL") terminated. You are NULL-terminating the array, not the strings. (0-termination of string literals is done by the compiler anyway.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The safest way is probably don't write into argv referred memory, (that may not be structured as you think), but having another bulk:

```
int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    const char* n_argv[] = { "param0", "param1", "param2" };
    argv = n_argv;
    ...
}
```

This will distract argv from it original memory (owned by the caller, that remains there) to another that will exist for the life of main().

Note that `const char*` is required to avoid the deprecated "*string assigned to char**" message.

---

NOTE: this code had been compiled with GCC 4.8.1 on Linux giving the following results:

```
make all 
Building file: ../main.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -c -std=c++11 -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
Finished building: ../main.cpp

Building target: e0
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  -o "e0"  ./main.o   
Finished building target: e0
```

Comment: Compiles  as -std=C++11 -Wall -pedantic with no error with GCC 4.8.1. Also, there is no 5, in my code, so you compiled something else.

Comment: The error in VS is `error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const char *[3]' to 'char *[]'`.

Comment: Please note `const char** argv` in my code (not just `char** argv`)

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Sorry for missing `const` *stupidly*. Is there a way to work through `main(int argc,char* argv[])`?

Comment: Not consistently: an initializer list is constant by definition. You can use `const_cast<char**>(n_argv)` in the assign, but in any case you are forcing a const to loose its const-ness.

Answer (score 5):

If you're able to use C99, you can use [compound literals](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-compound-literals/184401404) feature.  Here's an example that seems to work when compiled as `gcc -std=c99 main.c`:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    argv = (char *[]){"programName", "para1", "para2", "para3", NULL};

    char **p = argv;
    argc = 0;
    while (*p++ != NULL) {
        argc++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This cannot compile in VS.

Comment: @herohuyongtao That's why it starts with "if you can use C99," which VS doesn't support.

Comment: Please note that the question is tagged C++ (not C)

Comment: Note that if you do this, there are valid uses of the original argv that are invalid with the replacement argv:  user code can modify the original argument strings, but it can't modify the replacement argument strings (because they are string literals).

Comment: My bad, don't know why I thought it's about C language. I think `msvc` tag is missing, it might be important as VS doesn't always conform to C++ standard.

Answer (score 3):

Lets say your program takes a set of strings and does something on them. Lets call it `process_strings` which needs to be tested. You want to pass different sets of strings for different test cases, say `{"abc", "efg", "hij"}`, `{"thin", "run", "win"}`, `{"cat", "rat", "mat"}`, etc. In future you want to add more such test cases without altering your original function `process_strings`. Then the right way to go about this problem is to modify the (driver) program such that you don't have to recompile for different test cases added/removed. An example might be:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

// tested function
void process_strings(const std::vector<std::string>& params)
{
    for (auto iter = params.cbegin(); iter < params.cend(); ++iter)
        std::cout << *iter << '\t';
}

// driver program
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Insufficient data" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::ifstream test_file(argv[1]); // pass test cases file as an argument

    std::string test_case;    
    while (std::getline(test_file, test_case))
    {
        // each line is a test case
        std::istringstream iss(test_case);
        std::vector<std::string> params;
        // break parameters separated by ' ' blankspace
        copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),
             std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
             std::back_inserter(params));
        // if there're valid parameters, then pass it to the tested function
        if (!params.empty())
        {
            process_strings(params);
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Example of a test cases file, `tests.txt`:

```
abc efg
cat rat mat

animal man
```

The output produced for `C:\> simple.exe tests.txt`:

```
abc     efg
cat     rat     mat
animal  man
```

If you've arguments which contains space i.e. if space cannot be used as delimiter, then see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/236803/183120) on how to extract the arguments from the line.

Thus we've separated input data from code. Every time the test cases change, you needn't recompile the program. Just change the input, run it by the already compiled program and verify the output. This saves a lot of development time, and in some sense the basis of [data-driven programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-driven_programming).

Comment: Well, that depends on the error you're getting :) When you're asking something in a common forum, be as explicit as possible so that it's easy for others to understand you.

Comment: it's hard to find a solution for this kind of error :( hmm.. i'll check more