# C++ arguments to integer

Tags: c++, char, int, args

I am attempting to create a text file with the args[1] which should be an integer. The file name should be ex "3.txt", but the file i am getting is called just "t". The number argument is correct, but the file name is somehow getting incorrect. What suggestions do you have to improve this code both readability and usability?

```
int main(int argc,char *args[])
{
    ofstream myFile;
    int num = atoi(args[1]);

    myFile.open(num + ".txt");

    if (myFile.is_open()) 
    {
        myFile << "num\n" ;

        for(int i=num; i > 0; i--)
            myFile << i + ",";

        myFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't concatenate string literals like that (especially not with an integer...).  Don't ignore your warnings

Comment: @EdS. No warning in this case AFAICT. Offsetting a pointer is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Quentin: I suppose you're right.  I skimmed and didn't notice the small value of `num`

Comment: Putting in some larger number would have been *way* more fun.

Comment: sorry i was attempting java like syntax where that would make it a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problems are resulting from use of wrong types. First of all `int() + "text"` are defined, but does not do what you expect.  It's not operation on strings, but [on pointers](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html). You had better use a language. [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) contains [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and it will be easy wit him. Initially you should make string from `args[1]`:

```
string num(args[1]);
```

Of course, it [should be given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main) and you need to check it fitst!

```
if(argc < 2)
    //some throw
```

After it, operator `plus` will work in accordance with your wishes. So, you just add ".txt" to `num`.

```
num += ".txt"
```

Now you have to open file with [ofstrem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream). It expect `const char*`, and string on given address should ended with `'\0'` so you can use [std::basic_string::c_str](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str).

```
ofstream my_file(num.c_str());
```

Well to know, since [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) you can give just std::string:

```
ofstream my_file(num);
```

Let's get to the main ("C++ arguments to integer") topic. You can just use [std::stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol). As you can see, you don't need to worry about chars after number.

```
 for(int i=stoi(num); i > 0; i--)
      myFile << i << ","; //it can't be i + "," - as above
```

Or if you want to convert directly argument to integer, you have the ability to use [std::atoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi).

```
 int i = atoi(args[1]);
```

---

Finally begin of your code should looks like this:

```
 if(argc < 2)
   {//some throw}
 ofstream myFile;
 string num =string(args[1])+".txt";
 myFile.open(num.c_str());
```

Comment: `string num = args[1];` is sufficient

Comment: @Tacet Yours was the best OVERALL answer! Thank you for going above and beyond the question!

Answer (score 4):

Tricky one. When you do :

```
myFile.open(num + ".txt");
```

...you're not actually translating the int as a string. Instead, you're taking the `char const*` that is `".txt"` and offseting it by `num` (3 in your case) chars before passing it to open, hence your "t" file.

I see you're using C++. Save yourself some headaches by using `std::string`, and C++11's `std::to_string` functions if you can.

Comment: _"What you need to do is use strcat() or snprintf()"_ Cough!!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yeah well, I thought it was C at first. It's not fundamentally false, is it ? :p

Comment: I wouldn't consider this as a proper answer for c++ :-P ... Also you don't give a reasonable sample, what actually could be done in code.

Comment: There it goes. Never liked C-strings anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a reason why you are converting the command line argument to a number in 1st place here.

Change your code like

```
 myFile.open((std::string(argv[1]) + ".txt").c_str());
```

or for more recent compiler versions (capable of [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) standards)

```
 myFile.open(std::string(argv[1]) + ".txt");
```

You don't need to have `argv[1]` converted to be to a numeric value.

Comment: `myFile.open((std::string(argv[1]) + ".txt").c_str());` is all that's necessary

Comment: @NeilKirk Ah, I see. Just the parenthesis are enough?

Comment: Yes. You can use temporary string object from + operator that way.

Comment: your first option works, but the second one doesn't compile. Thanks!

Comment: @linux_security _"but the second one doesn't compile"_ I mentioned, it needs c++11 standard capabilities. Try to use the `-std=c++11` option with your current compiler, and it will be fine!

Comment: your code is not very readable/maintainable, you're trying to achieve too much in one line.

Comment: @linux_security _"your code is not very readable/maintainable, you're trying to achieve too much in one line"_ Well, regarding what you're showing and trying in your question `(myFile.open(num + ".txt");)`, that's a pretty arguable point :-P!

Comment: also if you look carefully at my code i needed the argument as an int for the for loop...

Comment: @linux_security Your question is unclear as most it can be. Please [improve](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26642416/edit) your question 1st, before giving critique on (seemingly) (in)valid answers!