# Pointer in C++ / Static Scope

Tags: c++, pointers

I have this code:

```
int foo() {
    int r = 100;
    int *s = &r;
    return *s;
}

void main() {
    cout << foo();
    system("pause");
}
```

I thought the result should be junk value, not 100.

But when I test it in Windows 8.1 and Mac OS X, the result is 100.

Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: It seems fairly straightforward to me that it should return 100. why do you think it should be junk?

Comment: Because when `return *s` , it will return the memory of `r` , but when `foo` was finished , the memory of `r` would be deleted . So I think the result should be junk value

Comment: It doesn't return the memory, doing `return *s` instead of `return s` means that you're returning the value at the address instead of the address. Your function returns `int`, not `int*`.

Comment: ya, I mean it will return the value of `r` , but when foo was finished , the address/memory of `r` would be released, so why it still returns 100 there?

Comment: @DươngAnhKhoa At return the return value is passed (constructed) before local variables go out of scope.

Comment: ok,thanks
This is a problem that my teacher had asked me today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because *s is simply the value that the pointer is pointing to.

if you have:

```
int a = 2;
int *b = &a;
printf("%d\n", *b);
a = 3;
printf("%d", *b);
```

it's gonna print:

```
2
3
```

but if you have:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 3;
int *c = &b;
printf("%d\n", a);
a = *c;
printf("%d\n", a);
*c = 5;
printf("%d\n", a);
```

it's gonna print

```
2
3
3
```

and not

```
2
3
5
```

because when you do `a = *c;` it just copies the value of c into a, but establishes no further relation between c and a, which means you can change c or the value that it's pointing to whatever you want, and a is gonna continue holding that value that c had when you did that assignment. They're 2 different spaces in memory and what `a = *c` does is merely copy the value that c is pointing to to a

What I mean by all that is that when you return `*s` you're not returning the address to the memory `s` is pointing to, but the value that it contains

Answer (score 2):

No, there shouldn't be a "junk value". `s` points to an object within the same scope, both `s` and `r` are destroyed when the function exits. You safely dereference `s` before `r` is destroyed.

Also `void main()` is incorrect.

Comment: `void main()` should instead be `int main()`

Most compilers will return an error when you use void instead of int.

Comment: To add to my previous comment. The reason you don't use `void main()` is because it is the standard to use `int main()` - You can read more about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main