# Simple program, cannot get for loop to execute

Tags: c++

Brand new programmer, so green behind the ears that I could be a frog. The intent of this program is to use a for loop (not a simple formula) to add all integers up to a user designated value. It executes all code up to the for loop perfectly, however the for loop does not seem to run. Here is the code in question:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
int main(int num=0)
{
    int sum = 0;
    std::cout << "This program will sum all integers up to a given value";
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Please enter a number "<<std::endl;
    std::cin >> num;
    std::cout << std::endl << "You've chosen the number  " << num<<std::endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; ++i)
        sum += i;
        return (sum);
    std::cout << "The sum of all numbers up to " << num << " is " << sum;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There are several variants, but you should generally use `int main (int argc, char *argv[]) { ... }` for[ "main"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main).  You should declare "num" *as a separate variable*!!!!

Comment: You are going to get noise for not looking carefully, but its a mistake we all made. Syntax is your enemy. C++ does not look at indentation like Python (#IHATEPYTHONFORTHISREASONONLY), the sum is returned to the operating system that called main(). sum is a variable and doesn't need returning.

Comment: the sum is returned to the operating system that called main() by the second last line before it gets to cout<<. The loop ends at i; on previous line

Comment: Good tips! I clearly have some bad habits to break...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You return the sum right after the loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= num; ++i)
    sum += i;
return (sum);
```

This means, you sum up the numbers and then exit the program before you print the result.

Comment: Thank you! I figured I had overlooked something fairly trivial. Lesson learned- return does not work like R.

Answer (score 2):

When it meets `return` for the first time, the program will be end.

Please put the `return` at the end of `main` function.

One more thing, shouldn't use parameter `num` in `main` function.

Write a separately function `sum_all_integers` and then call it in `main` function.

Answer (score 1):

Good news: your code works! The issue is that when `return (sum);` is called, the function is exited, and the line that would print out your answer is not executed.

I would also recommend adding the `using namespace std;` line after your includes, so that you don't end up with so much `std::` pollution. Also main should not take any arguments, so put that `int num=0` line inside the main block.

Oh, you should also be aware of your `return` line indentation.

Answer (score 0):

In this section

```
for (int i = 1; i <= num; ++i)
    sum += i;
    return (sum);
```

Your program will exit.

This boils down to what other answers have mentioned: `return` from `main` means exiting the program. Keep in mind that is is true even from within a loop like `while` or `for` - doing so is how one might design a search function which exits as soon as it has a result, for example.

To exit a `for` loop prematurely, use [`break`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/break). To continue to the next iteration and skip further code in the loop, use [`continue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/continue).

Also note that the indentation of `return` is misleading - it will be executed after the `for` loop, since the lack of brackets (`{}`) will make `for` only loop through the next line, which is `sum += i;` Keep in mind that C++ is *not* a whitespace sensitive language, so indentation means nothing to the logic (I like to abuse this in large blocks of similar code by tab-aligning). This is also a good example of why it is common practice to use brackets even when not strictly necessary. **EDIT** See also Apple's infamous "goto fail" bug.

Comment: Understood, and thanks for the explanation of blocks with the for loop. I wasn't sure how that would work...