# Problems with functions

Tags: c, function, getchar

I have two problems with the code, the first one being that the program wants me to enter my number twice and the second one being that the program closes down immediately after it has finished its process. 
I have tried to use the `getchar()` statement to stop it doing so but it doesn't seem to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int square(int);        /*function prototype*/

main()
{
    int x;              /*defining the function*/
    printf("Enter your number\n");
    scanf_s("%d \n", &x);       /*reading the users input*/
    printf("Your new answer is %d \n", square(x)); /*calling the function*/
    getchar();
    getchar();

}

int square(y) /*actual function*/
{
    return y * y;

}
```

Comment: If you use the `conio.h` library, it works better and you don't need to worry about this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using `scanf("%d", &x);` to read your number. Your problem is that your argument looks like this:`"%d \n"` so the program expects you to enter your number AND \n. This way, you say how you want your `x` to look, and in your case, it expects it to be a numeric value, a space and end of line.

As for the closing one, use `getch();`. For this function, you need to include the `conio.h` like you did with stdio, meaningly: `#include <conio.h>`.

Comment: Thanks that solved it all. 
I will use the `conio.h` library from now on. I will also find out what the differences are between the two libraries. Thanks a lot for answering my question, much appreciated

Comment: @bahjat Note that `conio.h` is non-standard and is not available on all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the issue by changing

```
scanf_s("%d \n", &x);
```

to

```
scanf_s("%d", &x);
```

The problem was that a whitespace character (space, newline etc) in the format string of `scanf` insructs `scanf` to scan and discard any number of whitespace characters, if any, until the first non-whitespace character.

---

As for the problem with `getchar()`, replace the first `getchar()` with:

```
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

This will scan and discard everything until a `\n` or `EOF`.

---

Also, change

```
main()
```

to

```
int main(void)
```

and

```
int square(y)
```

to

```
int square(int y)
```

Comment: If you work in C under Linux, you do not need `int main(void)`. You can use `void main(void)` or simply `main(){..}`.

Comment: @SimplyMe As per the latest standard, the valid forms of `main` are `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char** argv)`

Comment: @SimplyMe Linux or not, `void main()` is not standard C. `main` has a return type of `int`.http://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/2072269, http://stackoverflow.com/a/4207223/2072269

Comment: @CoolGuy, I asume you talk about the C11. And yes, that is true.

Comment: @muru, yes, but I assume you never worked under the linux platform? There are little differences and the `gcc` allows the simple `main` and adds the requirements depending on what SO version you have. Running on older versions would be nice to conform to the C99 version, instead of the C11, to be the same with the standard that was available in that time.

Comment: @SimplyMe Have a look at my profile. :) GCC works fine on Windows too. And note that `int main(...)` is accepted by older versions just fine. So a cautious use would always be `int`, not `void`.

Comment: @SimplyMe AFAIK, C89, C99 and C11 permits only `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char** argv)`. Otherwise, one should check if the implementation supports another signature of `main`. BTW, GCC will refuse to compile if you use `-pedantic-errors`.

Comment: @muru, I didn't say I use void. Right the opposite, I use int. But on his example he had no int so I didn't complicate it for him.