# Is int main(void) valid in C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

C++ standard lists allowed forms of `main`. It doesn't list `int main(void)` as an allowed form. But, it generally states that

> The parameter list (void) is equivalent to the empty parameter list

Is `int main(void)` an allowed form?

Comment: [Probably yes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44859345/2752075)

Comment: In C++ using an empty argument list is the same as using `void`. Both are equal and interchangeable. This is one of the *big* differences with C, where a function declared without any arguments (i..e empty set of parentheses `()`) can take any number of unspecified arguments.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat close as dupe perhaps? this is just a subset of that question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From *N3936* standard draft:

> 3.6 Start and termination
>
> 3.6.1 Main function
>
> 2 An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This
>   function shall not be overloaded. It shall have a declared return type
>   of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. An
>   implementation shall allow both
>
> — **a function of () returning int** and
>
> — a function of (int, pointer to pointer to char) returning int
>
> as the type of main (8.3.5).

Then:

> 8.3.5 Functions
>
> 4 ...
>   **A parameter list consisting of a single unnamed parameter of
>   non-dependent type void is equivalent to an empty parameter list.**
>   ...

Consequently,

```
int main(void)
```

is an allowed form of `main` function.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to comment of @Some programmer dude and @Edgar's answer, this is the part of *N3936* draft which explains given difference between C++ and standard C:

> C.1.7 Clause 8: declarators [diff.decl]
>
> 8.3.5
>
> Change: In C++, a function declared with an empty parameter list takes
>   no arguments. In C, an empty parameter list means that the number and
>   type of the function arguments are unknown.
>
> Example:
>
> int f(); // means int f(void) in C++
>   
>           // int f( unknown ) in C