# How do I declare the main() entry point of a program without specifying all arguments in C++?

Tags: c++, c

In C, I can do this to have an unspecified number of arguments in a function:

```
#include <elf.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern char **__environ;

int __libc_start_main
(
int (*main)(),
int argc,
char **argv
)
{
    int ret;
    Elf32_auxv_t *auxv;
    size_t aux[38];

    /* ... */

    exit(main(argc, argv, __environ, aux));
}
```

However, when doing this in C++, the compiler emits this error:

```
test.c: In function ‘int __libc_start_main(int (*)(), int, char**)’:
test.c:21:45: error: too many arguments to function
         exit(main(argc, argv, __environ, aux));
                                             ^
```

How do I do this in C++?

I understand that the C/C++ standards don't allow this, but I'm currently writing an implementation of the standard C library.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195384/discussion-on-question-by-jl2210-how-do-i-declare-the-main-entry-point-of-a-pr).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: You don't.

In C++ all functions have a prototype; there is no such thing as an "unspecified number of arguments".

If you want to call `main` as `main(argc, argv, __environ, aux)`, you need to declare it as `int (*main)(int, char **, char **, void *)` or similar.

Comment: I was wondering if one could have default values along with the function pointer definition like `int (*main)(int = 0, char ** = NULL, char ** = NULL, void * = NULL)`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That seems like a nifty feature, so I doubt C++ supports it.

Comment: I also doubt so, just too lazy to tryout myself now ;-). Anyways, compilers seem to handle `main()` in a special way.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ g++ errors out with `error: default arguments are only permitted for function parameters`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ [main is indeed very special](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4207223/332733)

Comment: @Mgetz The `main` in question is a local variable.

Comment: @JL2210 hence why I didn't close vote this as a duplicate

Answer (score 2):

Try either:

```
void foo(...);
```

or

```
template <typename ... ARGS> void foo(ARGS && ... args) { ... body }
```

First option is the same as `void foo()` (little known C language fact). First option requires some sort of additional argument (for example `printf(char *, ...)`, where first argument allows function to detect, how to parse following arguments).

Second option requires you to commit to a function body somewhere in a header.

Comment: `void foo(...)` is not legal C (per the grammar in C 2018 6.7.6, the *parameter-type-list* must have at least one parameter), and, if it were, it would not be equivalent to `void foo()`, due to rules about compatible types, at least.