# Error to my compiler-undefined reference to main

Tags: c++, reference, undefined, program-entry-point

I have an error... 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to`main'
I can't understand why I have that error.
Here is my program:

```
#include< iostream >
int n, m, a[101][101], viz[101];

using namespace std;

void DFS(int x)

{



int i;



viz[x]=1;

 for(i=1;i<=n;i++)

 if(a[x][i]==1 && viz[i]==0) DFS(i);

}

int Conex()

{int i;

DFS(1);

for(i=1; i<=n; i++)

if(viz[i]==0) return 0;

return 1;

}
```

what should I do?

Comment: All c++ programs need a `main` function. Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Your linker is correct. There is not `int main()` in the code that is shown.  Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main)

Answer (score 0):

You dont have a main function for this program, check the link  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function.

```
Use either int main {
                       // do your stuff
                     return 0;
                     }
or           void main {
                         // do your stuff
                        }
```

Comment: "void main" is an error (and gcc, used by OP, enforces it). Also missing parameters.