# "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" - once again (tiny example)

Tags: c++, g++

I am stuck with the apparently common yet very cryptic compilation error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I narrowed it down to a tiny implementation (from a tutorial) which just won't compile.

Header file: Num.h

```
class Num
{
 private:
 int num;
 public:
 Num(int n);
 int getNum();
};
```

Implementation: Num.cpp

```
#include "Num.h"
Num::Num(int n): num(n) {}
int Num::getNum()
{
 return num;
}
```

Compilation command:

```
g++  Num.cpp
```

I don't see any obvious hints in the invocation stack (via `g++  Num.cpp -v` ).

Both Num.h and Num.cpp are located in the same directory, so I don't get why the linker wouldn't be able to link them. I suspect that I might need to set some environment variable, but which one?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks for your patience - I know this error has been posted here a thousand times before, but I haven't found an answer that works for me.

Comment: Not cryptic at all, compiler couldn't find the program entry point.

Comment: Everything is cryptic when you don't know the terminology. Easy decryption of the error messages will come with time, practice, and often reading, reading, and more reading.

Answer (score 2):

By default you need `main` function, from which program execution starts from there, to build executable binary file.

You can use `-c` option like

```
g++ -c Num.cpp
```

to do compilation only (no linking) and get an object file `Num.o`.

Comment: Thanks for the super fast reply! Compiling without linking works indeed. However, I somehow need a way to compile the code _with_ linking because I'm using it as an include in a development tool that just compiles with g++ without giving the option to specify compile parameters. I also read about the need for a ```main``` so I tried adding a dummy one, but without success :-( header with main: ```class Num
{
 private:
 int num;
 public:
 int _main();
 Num(int n);
 int getNum();
}; ``` , implementation in .cpp ```int Num::_main(){}```

Comment: int main() is can not be a class member function. It's must be a free function. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main)

Comment: Thanks @drescherjm! Now it compiles with ```#include "Num.h"
int main(){}

Num::Num(int n): num(n) {}
int Num::getNum()
{
 return num;
} ```Yay!

Answer (score -1):

For reference, solution was to add a dummy `main` to Num.cpp in order to compile with g++.

```
#include "Num.h" 
int main(){}  
Num::Num(int n): num(n) {} 
int Num::getNum() {  return num; }
```

Comment: This probably does not do what you want, will produce an empty executable. The same as if you hadn't added anything but the main function.

Comment: You probably should add a `Num` object in your `main()`