# Invalid operands of types 'int' and '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to binary 'operator<<'

Tags: function, binary

my code;

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

main(){
    int t;cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int a;cin>>a;
        if(a==a&(-a)) cout<<a+(a==1?2:1)<<endl;
        else cout<<a&(-a)<<endl;
    }
}
```

```
Error: s Perfect Bitmasks Classroom.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
s Perfect Bitmasks Classroom.cpp|9|error: invalid operands of types 'int' and '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to binary 'operator<<'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Please can anyone help me fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is simple, and the error message already hinted as to what it is. Line 9 is as follows:

```cpp
else cout<<a&(-a)<<endl;
```

Now you probably think that this line is supposed to be parsed as (note extra parentheses) this:

```cpp
else cout<< (a&(-a)) <<endl;
```

However, it's being parsed as this:

```cpp
else (cout<<a) & ((-a)<<endl);
```

The compiler doesn't know what to do with the expression `(-a)<<endl`. The left-hand side of the expression, `(-a)`, is an `int`, while the right-hand side, `endl`, is what the compiler sees as an `<unresolved overloaded function type>`, hence the error message.

There are several other problems with your code.

1. *Never* use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`. It is non-standard and only works with some compilers: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)
2. The declaration for function `main()` is wrong. Its return type must be an `int`. Anything else is non-standard: [What is the proper declaration of main in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main-in-c)
3. The expression `a==a&(-a)` may not do what you want. You may think that it means `a == (a&(-a))` (again, note extra parentheses), when instead it means `(a==a) & (-a)`.