# From vector does not name a type To expected unqualified id / C++ brute force

Tags: c++, vector, ide, brute-force

Long story short. Im trying to run this code in VS Studio IDE.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++){
            for(int j = i + 1; j < nums.size(); j++){
                if(nums[i] + nums[j] == target){
                    return {i, j};
                }
            }            
        }
        return {};
    }
};
```

I had to add #include  to get the first problem resolved.
But now its saying:

**using-declaration for non-member at class scope**

**expected unqualified-id before '<' token**

The plot thickens. It runs fine on leetcode without the #include . None of this transpires.

Is it a vector issue or what? And why does VS Studio code hate this but it runs fine on leetcode?
https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/solutions/1439021/c-brute-force-hashmap-solutions/?q=brute&orderBy=most_votes&languageTags=cpp

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++){
            for(int j = i + 1; j < nums.size(); j++){
                if(nums[i] + nums[j] == target){
                    return {i, j};
                }
            }            
        }
        return {};
    }
};
```

OG code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get a compile error in VSCode or is it just the editor complaining? Also the code should not compile into a program because its missing an `int main()`

Comment: VSCode is complaining. Can you elaborate on what you mean by compile into a program?
@drescherjm

'C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crtexewin.o): in function main:
C:/M/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexewin.c:70: undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status' 


It does this now with adding int main() but it did that before too.

Comment: In c++ it is required to have a main function. This answer explains what the valid signatures: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main-in-c)

Comment: If you have saved your file and have your `int main() { // code here }` you should not have the error about WinMain. The linker in MinGW looks for main() first then WinMain if it finds neither it ends with an error about WinMain. Also note that running the build or debug tasks will not automatically save your code first by default.

Comment: @drescherjm Well int main() is there and it gave me that. So there must be another element or reason it'll do that. Unless my ide isnt set up right o something. I dont understand what youre trying to say. Its there. But yeah im saving it before I run. Thanks.

Comment: "undefined reference to `WinMain`" tells me that you likely created your solution as a Windows GUI application instead of a console application.  The linker is looking for a the GUI entrypoint function (`WinMain`) instead of the standard C++ entrypoint (`main`).  Create a new solution and make sure to configure it as a console application.

Comment: Is `int main()` in a different source file? Remember that VSCode by default only builds the active file. In the default mode without build extensions like CMakeTools or MakeFileTools you have to edit your tasks.json if you have more than 1 cpp file.

Comment: @drescherjm Well removing the int main from another .cpp file seemed to keep that error from popping up. But now its 'empty' and doing the same thing I posted in Edit 2 on here from the console.

Comment: BTW, Here is the information on how to get VSCode to compile more than 1 file: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I would NOT recommend the use of `using` at header level because of namespace clashes, if you really want to use it, consider the version below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++){
            for(int j = i + 1; j < nums.size(); j++){
                if(nums[i] + nums[j] == target){
                    return {i, j};
                }
            }            
        }
        return {};
    }
};
```

That said, most people would agree that the approach below looks more "modern"

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <optional>

class Solution {
public:
    std::optional< std::tuple<int,int> > twoSum( const std::vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        for( int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
            for(int j = i + 1; j < nums.size(); j++) {
                if( nums[i] + nums[j] == target){
                    return {{i, j}};
                }
            }            
        }
        return {};
    }
};


int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec{1,2,3,4};
    int total = 5;
    Solution s;
    auto result = s.twoSum( vec, total );
    if ( result ) {
        auto [i,j] = result.value();
        std::cout << vec[i] << " + " << vec[j] << " = " << total << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked. But I barely understand why this works Seems you separated the two and made int main another instance. Seems you also rewrote the code and defined the vector differently. Dont understand. But thanks for sure. But dont understand the answer, haha

Comment: The answer is just the first. The second code is just an improvement using `optional` and `tuple`.

Comment: Ah, doesnt work then. It gives me this again: 

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crtexewin.o): in function `main':
C:/M/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexewin.c:70: undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You need a main function so it does something with that class.

Comment: The solution class? So I need to look up functions for the class solution?

Comment: So I added int main () and added ';' to all the lines it kept saying it expected one at and now it gives me a blank run. It runs now so thats progress? See Edit 2. @Nole Ksum