# How to pass a template class and a normal class to a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <typename T>
class myTemplateClass
{
public:
    myTemplateClass()
    {
        // do something
    }

    myTemplateClass(T t)
        : val{t}
    {
        // do something
    }
    T val;
};

class mySimpleClass
{
public:
    mySimpleClass()
    {
        // do something
    }
};

template <template<typename> class TT, typename T = void>
auto create()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<TT<T>, myTemplateClass<T>>)
    {
        // do something
        // and return
        return myTemplateClass<T>();
    }
    else
    {
        //constexpr (std::is_same_v<TT, mySimpleClass>)
        // do something
        // and return
        return  mySimpleClass{};
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        auto result = create<myTemplateClass<int>>();
    }
    {
        auto result = create<mySimpleClass>();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to implement one `create()` function which return one of a template class and a normal class based on template parameter, but it has an error.

How can I implement `create()` to support this situation?

mostly, it is used as like

```
create<int>();
create<double>();
```

but if I want to mix as like create<myTemplateClass>() and create in one create function based one template function, is there any way?

Comment: `void main(char**, int)` isn't a valid signature for main. See [What is the proper declaration of main in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4207134/11082165)

Comment: You can't pass `mySimpleClass` to a template template argument. Also, since `TT` is a template template argument, `create<myTemplateClass<int>>()` would need to be `create<myTemplateClass, int>()` instead.  Since you are passing two types to `create()`, not templates, what's wrong with simply using: `template <typename T> T create() { return T{}; }`? Why are you trying to filter the types?

Comment: if so, what is proper value for "??????" part in code     'if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, myTemplateClass<?????>>)'

Comment: I just want to simple create function for creating instance of mySimpleClass or instance of myTemplateClass<T>.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename> class TT
```

`TT` is a template.

```
std::is_same_v<TT, mySimpleClass>
```

Both parameters to `std::is_same_v` are types, and not templates. The first parameter specified, `TT`, is a template instead of a type. This is the reason for your compilation error.

It is unclear what was the intent here, so it's not possible to suggest, with reasonable certainty, what should this be changed to.

Comment: Likewise neither `create<myTemplateClass<int>>` nor `create<mySimpleClass>` make sense, since `myTemplateClass<int>` and `mySimpleClass` are types, not templates.

Comment: if so, what value can I specify for "?????" part in  'if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, myTemplateClass<?????>>'

Comment: I just want to create one simple create method as template which return mySimpleClass or return myTemplateClass<int>

Comment: You need to provide a step by step specification that defines which template parameters result in one class, and which template paramers result in the other one. You might have them in your head, but we don't.

Answer (score 1):

##### Mistake 1

First things first, the signature of `main` in your example is not correct. Ideally it should be `int main()`(instead of `void main(char**, int)`.

---

##### Mistake 2

Moreover, `myTemplateClass<int>` is a **class-type** not a **class-template**.

One way to solve this would be:

```
template <typename Type>
auto create()
{
    return Type{};
};
```